# What is the rule for adjective order?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, noun-phrases

I remember being taught that the correct order of adjectives in English was something along the lines of "Opinion-Size-Age-Color-Material-Purpose."

However, it's been a long time and I'm pretty sure I've forgotten a few categories
(I think there were eight or nine). Can anyone fill them in?

Comment: great question - I had never heard of these rules; always just played it by ear, so to speak, from least specific to most specific.

Comment: @cori - the fascinating linguistic point is that native speakers will have subconsciously inferred a rule like this without it ever being stated. The "rule" is really an observation of what they do. All languages and dialects consist of such unconscious rules.

Comment: For grammatical explanation please refer to this one - http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/65027/3463

Comment: Is this a English language thing? or do other languages have a similar rule?

Comment: @mcfedr: This is an English-language site, thus this question is limited to English. All languages do have rules for word order. Not necessarily remotely similar to the rules of English, but you certainly can't just slap any adjective at all after any adjective at all and call it a day.

Comment: @NathanLong  ..and CAN there be a rule !?  ' old Chinese wine and            ' Chinese old wine' are both grammatically correct  - and  have different meanings.

Comment: Based on the answers and comments, the Layman's Conclusions I'm drawing are: (1) classifiers always go next to the noun; (2) when in doubt, do whatever Ngrams says is most common; (3) if Ngrams says all combos are rare, specify adjectives in separate sentences (i.e. dodge the problem).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we order our adjectives in certain ways: "big, blue house" rather than "blue, big house"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/599423/why-do-we-order-our-adjectives-in-certain-ways-big-blue-house-rather-than-b)

Comment: @RobertColumbia You mean the question that was asked 12 years after this one?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

I am re­mind­ed of how J.R.R. Tol­kien’s moth­er once fa­mous­ly
cor­rect­ed him at a very ear­ly age when he said ‘a green great drag­on’.
She told him that it had to be ‘a great green drag­on’, but when he asked
her why, she couldn’t an­swer, there­by start­ing him down the road of
puz­zling over mat­ters of philology (linguistics) his whole life long.

This top­ic is one of con­tin­u­ing re­search. Sim­ply goog­ling for
‘ad­jec­tive or­der­ing re­stric­tions’ (AOR) or ‘ad­jec­tive hi­er­ar­chy’
can un­cov­er some fas­ci­nat­ing re­search in this area.

In her 2006 pa­per on [“Ad­jec­tive Order­ing Re­stric­tions
Re­vis­it­ed”](http://www.lingref.com/cpp/wccfl/25/paper1473.pdf) on pp
309–407 of the *Pro­ceed­ings of the 25ᵗʰ West Coast Con­fer­ence on
For­mal Lin­guis­tics*, Alex­an­dra Te­o­dor­es­cu writes:

> Ad­jec­tive or­der­ing re­stric­tions (AOR) have been wide­ly dis­cussed,
> but they are still not very well un­der­stood.  For ex­am­ple, in
> lan­guages like English pre­nom­i­nal ad­jec­tives are strict­ly or­dered.
>
> …
>
> For ex­am­ple, ad­jec­tives that de­note qual­i­ty have been ar­gued to
> pre­cede ad­jec­tives con­vey­ing size, which in turn pre­cede ad­jec­tives
> con­vey­ing shape, and so on, in all lan­guages (5). Sim­i­lar claims have
> been made for oth­er ad­jec­tive types, and the re­spec­tive or­der­ing
> re­stric­tions are giv­en in (6).
>
> - (5) Qual­i­ty > Size > Shape > Color > Prov­e­nance [Sproat and Shih (1991)]
> - (6) a. Posses­sive > Speak­er-ori­ent­ed > Sub­ject-ori­ent­ed >Man­ner/The­mat­ic  [Cinque (1994)]
> - b. Value > Di­men­sion > Phys­i­cal prop­er­ty > Speed > Hu­man Propen­si­ty > Age > Color [Dixon (1982)]

See Teodor­es­cu’s bib­li­og­ra­phy to chase down re­lat­ed work. You
should al­so look for pa­pers that cite hers (Google Schol­ar finds [26 such
ci­ta­tions](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=+Adjective+Ordering+Restrictions+Revisited+Teodorescu+&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C6)
to her work), like Lu­cas Cham­pi­on’s 2006 pa­per on [“A Game-The­o­ret­ic
Ac­count of Ad­jec­tive Order­ing
Restric­tions”](http://www.lingref.com/cpp/wccfl/25/paper1473.pdf), which
starts off with the Tol­kien ex­am­ple.

Build­ing then on Cham­pi­on’s work is this English-lan­guage pa­per by
An­to­nia An­drout­so­pou­lou, Ma­nuel Es­pañol-Eche­va­rría, and Phil­ippe
Pré­vost en­ti­tled [“On the Ac­qui­si­tion of the Prenom­i­nal Place­ment
of Eval­u­a­tive Ad­jec­tives in L2
Spanish”](http://www.lingref.com/cpp/hls/10/paper1781.pdf), from the 10ᵗʰ His­pan­ic Lin­guis­tics Sym­po­si­um in 2008. This one is in­ter­est­ing
be­cause it looks at how sec­ond-lan­guage learn­ers ac­quire an
un­der­stand­ing of ad­jec­tive or­der­ing when learn­ing a new lan­guage:

> In this pa­per, we fur­ther in­ves­ti­gate knowl­edge of ad­jec­ti­val
> or­der­ing re­stric­tions in for­eign lan­guage learn­ing, by fo­cus­ing on
> L2 ac­qui­si­tion of eval­u­a­tive ad­jec­tives (EAs) in Span­ish by French
> learn­ers.

The most re­cent pro­fes­sion­al pub­li­ca­tion I could find on this is­sue
is Katy Mc­Kin­ney-Bock­’s 2010 pa­per on [“Ad­jec­tive Class­es and
Syn­tac­tic Or­der­ing
Re­stric­tions”](http://elanguage.net/journals/index.php/lsameeting/article/download/650/630),
in which she writes:

> There is a lack of con­sen­sus in the lit­er­a­ture as to which
> clas­si­fi­ca­tion of ad­jec­tives is di­rect­ly rel­e­vant for the
> ob­served syn­tac­tic re­stric­tions on their or­der­ing. In this pa­per, I
> ar­gue that ad­jec­tives are di­vid­ed in­to four class­es of rel­e­vance
> for syn­tac­tic or­der­ing. I pro­pose that ad­jec­tive or­der­ing
> re­stric­tions (AOR) are the re­sult of ad­jec­ti­val con­stit­u­ents
> rais­ing or not rais­ing in the struc­ture as a con­se­quence of their
> com­plex­i­ty, rather than stip­u­lat­ing that se­man­tic prop­er­ties
> cor­re­late to syn­tac­tic heads.

and whose ex­tend­ed ab­stract reads:

> I ar­gue there are four class­es of ad­jec­tives rel­e­vant to
> syn­tac­tic or­der­ing: pred­ica­tive/in­ter­sec­tive,
> pred­ica­tive/non-in­ter­sec­tive, non-pred­ica­tive, clas­si­fy­ing
> (Sven­on­i­us 2008, Al­ex­i­a­dou et al 2007), and pre­vi­ous pro­pos­als
> have not iden­ti­fied the rel­e­vant se­man­tic di­men­sions.  Among the
> prop­er­ties of grad­abil­i­ty, mass/count, and in­ter­sec­tiv­i­ty, on­ly
> in­ter­sec­tiv­i­ty is syn­tac­ti­cal­ly rel­e­vant. The four class­es of
> ad­jec­tives are mo­ti­vat­ed by the dis­tri­bu­tion of
> or­dered/non-or­dered ad­jec­tives, scope ef­fects with cer­tain
> ad­jec­tive-pairs, PP-mod­i­fi­ca­tion, N-drop­ping and com­par­a­tives
> (Bouchard 2002, Hig­gin­both­am 1985, Ken­nedy 1999). DP struc­ture
> in­volves 1) merg­ing the clas­si­fy­ing ad­jec­tive with pro­nounced N, 2)
> merg­ing in­ter­sec­tive ad­jec­tives with N, 3) merg­ing
> non-in­ter­sec­tive ad­jec­tives with a silent copy of N.

Fi­nal­ly, if you’re look­ing for some­thing slight­ly less pro­fes­sion­al
— or at least, less aca­dem­ic — then in [this blog
post­ing](http://literalminded.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/ordering-your-adjectives/),
the wri­ter pos­its an or­der­ing of:

- eval­u­a­tion
- size
- shape
- con­di­tion
- hu­man pro­pen­si­ty
- age
- col­or
- ori­gin
- ma­te­ri­al
- at­trib­u­tive noun

And sum­ma­rizes with:

> If there’s def­i­nite­ly a mean­ing dif­fer­ence be­tween dif­fer­ent
> ad­jec­tive or­der­ings, let that de­ter­mine how you or­der them, and
> don’t use com­mas. If you can’t find a mean­ing dif­fer­ence, don’t go
> try­ing to force there to be one. In­stead, go by the
> ad­jec­tive-or­der­ing hi­er­ar­chy, and don’t use com­mas.  If more than
> one ad­jec­tive has the same kind of mean­ing in the hi­er­ar­chy, then use
> com­mas, or ands or buts if the ad­jec­tives have con­tras­tive mean­ings.

There’s a lot more out there on this top­ic.

Comment: A shiny big diamond versus a big shiny diamond?

Comment: @JoeZ. I'd read "shiny" as being a condition, so my choice would be "big shiny diamond".

Comment: Reminds me of the BANGS adjectives in French

Comment: @Mehrdad except BANGS is whether the adjective goes before or after the noun, whereas AOR seems to be the order of the adjectives relative to each other.

Comment: If there are great dragons and minor dragons, you certainly can talk about a green great dragon, especially if most of the great dragons are red.

Comment: Uh… where does *Adjective ordering restrictions (AOR) have been widely discussed, but they are still not very well understood* come from, please?

If that were true, large numbers of native speakers would be getting the AOR wrong much of the time.

How many of us think that happens?

How many think almost everyone gets it right almost all the time, and that means they do understand it?

Comment: Drew, I think you're wholly correct but green great dragon when most great dragons are red is a case of contradistinction, not every-day speech.

Comment: What is this about rules from different languages not being useful?

Vocabulary is comparable. Grammar is comparable. Everything else is comparable and the differences as much as the similarities can be hugely helpful in understanding how and why different languages work. 

Why should adjective ordering restrictions not be comparable?

Comment: I wonder about these "rules." Does shape really come before age? *An old, square table* or a *square, old table?*

Answer (score 167):

> Michael Swan (Practical English Usage,
>   Oxford University Press, 1997) writes:
>
> "Unfortunately, the rules for
>   **adjective order** are very complicated, and different grammars
>   disagree about the details" p. 8
>
> He does, however, go on to list some
>   of the most important rules:
>
> 1. Adjectives of **colour**, **origin**, **material** and **purpose** usually go in that order.
>
>    - Colour-origin-material-purpose-noun
>    - **red Spanish leather riding** boots
>    - **A brown German beer** mug
>    - **A Venetian glass flower** vase
> 2. Other adjectives usually go before words of colour, origin, material and
>      purpose. It is impossible to give
>      exact rules, but adjectives of
>      **size**, **length** and **height** often come first.
>
>    - The **round** glass table (NOT the glass round table)
>    - A **big**, modern brick house (NOT a modern, big brick house)
>    - **Long**, flexible steel poles
>    - A **tall**, ancient oak-tree
> 3. Adjectives which express **judgements** or **attitudes** usually come before all others.
>      Examples are lovely, definite, pure,
>      absolute, extreme, perfect, wonderful,
>      silly.
>
>    - A **lovely**, long, cool drink
>    - Who's that **silly** fat man over there?
> 4. **Numbers** usually go before adjectives.
>
>    - **Six** large eggs
>    - The **second** big shock
>
>    **First**, **next** and **last**
>      most often go before one, two, three
>      etc.
>
>    - The **first** three days
>    - My **last** two jobs."
>
> pp. 8-9
>
> He does not mention **age**, which
>   would normally go after adjectives of
>   size, length and height, but before
>   colour, origin, material and purpose.
>
> - A big **old** straw hat.
> - A charming **young** university student.
>
> Thus, a complete list could be:
>
> **(article) + number + judgement/attitude + size, length,
>   height + age + colour + origin +
>   material + purpose + noun**
>
> - a lovely long black leather coat
> - a valuable Dutch Impressionist painting
> - a rustic old stone holiday cottage

[*Reference:* [BritishCouncil.org](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/order-adjectives)]

Comment: Yes, a good answer. Part of the problem is that this is not usually taught to English speakers because (unlike some so-called rules) it doesn't need to be: it's an example of a rule which really is in native English. The downside of this is that most English speakers are not aware there even are rules, and can't explain them to foreign learners.

Comment: Note that the purpose words above (riding, beer, and flower) are not strictly adjectives. Even "riding", which as a participle is adjective-ish, is really more of a gerund: the boots are not actually riding; they are for riding, which is an activity. So perhaps a modification of the rule is that descriptive nouns follow all the true adjectives.

Comment: @moloci You are talking about noun adjuncts (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).  They used to also be called adjectival nouns, which illustrates that it is common to connect them to adjectives.  Although they have superficial qualities that seem to be the same as adjectives, you are right that they don't behave identically.  Interestingly, in German, things that would be noun adjuncts in English are generally orthographically combined with the main noun to make a compound word.  That is why you get those long-looking German words.

Comment: Thanks for this question and answer. As a native English speaker, I have been doing this for years without realising it, as Colin Fine points out.

Comment: Some of those examples are a bit disingenuous. For example, it would be perfectly possible to speak of a *modern, big brick house* if the house was made of big bricks. Many of the words in these lists aren't actually adjectives - they're nouns, and if those nouns are themselves modified by other elements *within the list*, such modifiers invariably come immediately before the noun.

Comment: @TheEnglishChicken: For some reason, although "large", "tiny", "small" and many other *size* adjectives seem to follow the rule order for size as discussed in this question, "big" and "huge" don't, e.g. "big bad wolf", "big beautiful women", "huge beautiful sculpture" etc. tend not to.

Comment: It's about scope. *Venetian glass flower vase*: **(Venetian glass) (flower vase)** or **(Venetian (glass (flower vase)))**. The vase is a flower vase. It is made of Venetian glass. No other order makes sense in this example. *flower glass Venetian vase*? *flower Venetian glass vase*? *glass flower Venetian vase*? Nope. And when different orders make sense then typically mean slightly different things. It's about which words modify which others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, they're not disingenuous. People prefer life's problems to come with lucid, sequential rules, and so they come up with them. Then they give a whole bunch of examples without looking back and seeing that actually the rule, even if claimed to be general and not absolute, is actually bunk in many cases. Honestly I could rearrange almost every example given in this answer without it sounding weird, except for the "numbers before other adjectives" rule, probably because they're a category by themselves, quantifiers/determiners.

Comment: @Zebrafish: I don't agree *at all*. I'm sure that only a tiny fraction of native speakers have ever heard of anything like "The Royal Order of Adjectives", but that obviously doesn't stop them from stringing adjectives together "correctly" from the perspective of other native speakers. *Learners* want "rules" that they can learn (as do *teachers*, so they've got something "definite" to teach), but that's not how language works for native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have a feeling you misunderstood me. I agreed with your comment entirely, that's why I upvoted it. My point is exactly the one you made, people want rules but sometimes there aren't clear exact rules, and native speakers who've never studied grammatical or syntactic rules can speak just as eloquently as someone else, provided they have right stimuli, exposure to other speakers. I agree with you 100%.

Comment: @Zebrafish: My apologies. You're quite right - I *did* misunderstand you. But it's certainly been interesting over the last few years to see how rapidly computer-based natural language processing has advanced since they stopped trying to do this using "rules" primarily defined by linguists/grammarians. By now we all know [*verbing weirds language.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22verbing+weirds+language%22) Are we ready yet to handle the fact that *language weirds rules?* (And can I safely ignore Google Chrome's red line under *weirds* as I write this? :)

Answer (score 23):

The order in which native English speakers generally use adjectives is called the 'Royal Order of Adjectives.'

The Royal Order of Adjectives is as follows:

1. Determiners (e.g. *the, this*)
2. Observations
3. Size
4. Shape
5. Age
6. Color
7. Nationality
8. Material
9. Type

For example, we would say:

> Joyce Carol Oates is the [determiner] premier [observation] American [nationality] novel [type] writer.

You can read more about the royal order of adjectives [here](http://zencomma.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/those-adjectives-need-a-comma/.).

Comment: To show how complicated this topic is, I think "The Royal Order of Adjectives" is slightly wrong. Age goes **before** shape. Consider [this ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=old+rectangular%2Crectangular+old%2C+new+spherical%2C+spherical+new&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). (If you have adjectives for age, size, **and** shape, my Ngram skills are not sufficient to determine the usual order empirically, but I would definitely say *big old rectangular building*.)

Comment: Possibly "The Royal Order of Adjectives" was confused by the adjectives *thin, fat, tall, short,* which seem to count as adjectives of size and not shape (but come after plain adjectives of size like big and small).

Comment: I object with anything named "royal", as well as the notion of king- or queendom.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I don't for one moment believe these "orders of precedence" are either universally applied or internally consistent. But your NGram uses what seem to me quirky pairings. The more "natural" [round young face](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=round+young+face%2Cyoung+round+face&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) seems like proof enough to me that **shape goes before age**.

Comment: There are far more [fat old women](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fat+old+women%2Cold+fat+women&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than *old fat women*.

Comment: I think this just means that there is no one ordering, it just simply happens to be the case that, only most of the time, such an ordering is followed. Which is, if nothing else, just a sign of things to come for both ESL folks and NLP.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But far more [old square tables](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=old+square+table%2Csquare+old+table&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cold%20square%20table%3B%2Cc0) than square old tables. For 'rule' read 'guideline'. As per usual.

Comment: @Edwin: What I find fascinating here is that presumably both of us looked at the 'rule' and *thought up* our counterexamples. We didn't go looking through *actual corpora* to come up with them in the first place, and I think it's not unreasonable to suggest that we could each have produced our examples even if we'd never encountered those specific sequences before in our lives. *And,* somewhat more crucially, we *fully expected* the corpora to bear out our expectations.

Comment: We're either {modesty forbids} or just very old.

Comment: I'm not saying that for *every* disparate set of adjectives there's always a specific sequence that everyone would agree on, but there do seem to be sequences we *do* agree on even though we must be doing this without reference to explicit formal rules. In other words, we're (subconsciously) aware of rules which we can successfully *apply*, but which (thus far) we can't *articulate*.

Answer (score 14):

The European Union distinguishes between "Scottish Smoked Salmon" and "Smoked Scottish Salmon", the former indicating where the fish was smoked, and the latter indicating where the fish was caught/bred.

The rule seems to be that the locative adjective directly precedes the noun or verb it refers to.

Comment: I like to view these with parenthesis. (Scottish (Smoked Salmon)) is Smoked Salmon primarily but is also Scottish, while (Smoked (Scottish Salmon)) is Scottish Salmon primarily but is also Smoked.

Comment: @AaronFranke Really? Well that would give you the opposite meaning to the meaning I thought it had. In my head, I parse the phrases as "Scottish–smoked salmon" and "smoked Scottish–salmon".

Comment: 'Smoked Scottish salmon' follows the usual rules, but 'Scottish smoked salmon' is (using usual practice rather than adopting a stipulative definition) ambiguous, probably defaulting to 'both caught and smoked there'. 'Scottish-smoked salmon' means smoked in Scotland, though the usual rules don't insist it was caught there (perhaps carted in from below the border to be smoked).

Answer (score 3):

Without going into details, the general principle seems to be that **the more intrinsic or essential the quality of the object is, the closer to the noun the adjective should be**, and the more accidental, the further away from it.

a beautiful, new, red, American, sports car

To help understand the idea of intrinsic/essential quality versus accidental quality, think of changing those qualities — think of Harold Chasen in *Harold and Maude* (a 1971 film by Hal Ashby) turning a Jaguar E-Type into a hearse.

The less essential the quality, the easier the transformation:
*beautiful* is a matter of opinion, so you only have to ask another person to change the adjective,
from *new* to *as good as new*, a little dent is enough,
from *red* to any other colour, a little coat of paint,
from *American* to *Italian* or *Japanese*, serious body modifications are needed,
from *sports car* to *hatchback*, drastic modifications of body, engine, etc.

Comment: I think this is not well-defined, and the example is picked to fit the narrative. It's easy to find examples to the contrary. Especially regarding size and nationality. But we don't even need to do that, we can stick with your example. By your reasoning, as time passes the new red car turns into a red old car. And it makes no difference at all if I say it's a big fat car or a fat big car.

Comment: There's something to this, though. It might not be "intrinsic" but how specific to the object the adjective is, eg practically anything can be beautiful but only a handful of things can be "sports" things, etc.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Except who would actually say> a fat, big car?

Comment: @RegDwigнt: 'fat' and 'big' are at the same level, that is why you could say 'a fat, big car' OR 'a big, fat car'! Whereas with 'old' and 'red' the level is different, and 'a new, red car' progressively turns into 'an old, red car' and not 'a red, old car'...

Answer (score 1):

Page 974 of Garner's fourth edition reads

> *Two worst*, not **worst two*: the first, which is more logical than
> the second, has always predominated in print.

I do not why the first one more logical though. According to Google ngrams, we say *the two best/worst* but *the first/next/last two.*

Comment: Numerals are not considered adjectives by any grammarians nowadays (and not even considered quantifiers by many).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth https://imgur.com/gallery/xr3g3WF

Comment: Try CGEL. [This thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130448/is-five-an-adjective/130457#130457) for starters.