# How can I join many adjectives to one word and create a grammatical phrase?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

I have to describe an object that is:
a pair of

- round/rounded earrings,
- made of wood/wooden,
- with bosses of brass/brass bossed?

How can I put it in a single statement?

I think that it could be right to say "round wooden earrings with bosses of brass" but I'm not sure, since I'm not a native speaker of English.

Comment: Related: [Adjective order](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1155/).

Comment: If you use it, "brass bossed" should be hyphenated ("brass-bossed") because it functions as a single adjective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"round wooden earrings with brass bosses" is the most natural way of saying this to the English ear, although you could say "brass bossed round wooden earrings"

My personal thought  is it's probably better to put whatever you consider to be the most important features first qualifying them after with the less important ones.

Comment: "Round wooden earrings with brass bosses" seems just fine: thank you!

Comment: To elaborate: usage of genitive of material ("bosses of brass") in English is overwhelmingly not used, though it is grammatical. Unless there are are definite stylistic reasons, the genitive is replaced with an ordinary adjective, "brass bosses", as the answers describe.

Comment: I agree that "round wooden earrings with brass bosses" is the most natural. But for your other, I would write "brass-bossed round wooden earrings" instead.