# "Local crumbed scallops", or "crumbed local scallops"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Recently I was in a fish and chip shop in [Mandurah, WA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandurah), selling local crumbed scallops.

- Is *local crumbed scallops* the correct form?
- Is *crumbed local scallops* more appropriate?
- What if "nonlocal" scallops were also available?
- [optional] What form would a native German speaker find more natural, and why?

Comment: Related (dupe?): [Adjective order](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/).

Comment: Here is an order http://www.english-the-easy-way.com/Adjectives/Adjectives_Order.htm but I can't decide on whether `local` and `crumbed` appear as Origin and Qualifier

Comment: It would be an exact duplicate if it would not be asking the last two "sub-questions".

Comment: @JoseK: _local_ is used to mean the origin of the scallops.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: and `crumbed` ? In my comment, I meant `local` was an *Origin* adjective and `crumbed` was a *Qualifier/Purpose* but was not sure.

Comment: @JoseK: I thought you were not sure about _local_. I would classify _crumbed_ as _material_ because it means _covered with crumbs_.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks *crumbed* sounds strange? Shouldn't it be *breaded*?

Comment: 'Local' may not be unusual, but 'crumbed' certainly is. And how does one classify 'crumbed' semantically? And which tweaked version of the 'Royal Order' (this discussed elsewhere) is best? Will 'crumbed' be listed ... if so, in which category/ies? There are exceptions to 'the rules'.  Here, I'd say the less-odd-sounding option is the one to go with, and that this will vary even among practised Anglophones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A discussion of adjective ordering is the right approach here I think, but...

To me, “local crumbed scallops” would be already-crumbed scallops obtained locally; “crumbed local scallops” would be scallops obtained locally and then crumbed after being obtained.

Comment: Similar cases might be a matter of law. In the UK, smoked salmon may legally be sold as "smoked Scottish salmon" only if the fish were caught in Scottish waters; salmon caught elsewhere and smoked in Scotland are sometimes sold as "Scottish smoked salmon", though [that is not recommended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoked_salmon#Labelling).

Answer (score 2):

*Local crumbed scallops* seems ambiguous, as it could be understood as *local-crumbed scallops*, where *local* is referring to *crumbed*; in that case, the hyphen is necessary to avoid the ambiguity.
*Crumbed local scallops* is more clear, as it's evident that *local* is referring to *scallops*.

In English, the adjectives are written (or should be written) in a particular order; the answers given in [Adjective order](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/adjective-order) explain better in which order they should be written.

*Non-local* is generally not used; if the scallops are not local scallops, then they are generally called *scallops*.

Comment: Here's a page that has a nice little table that shows the order of adjectives: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adjectives.htm

Answer (score 1):

There is a theory that adjective ordering is essentially universal (i.e. the same across all languages), so that in principle we ought to be able to give rules something like this:

- keep words forming a compound or colloquation together;
- if the adjectives all come before the noun in your native language, keep them in that same order in English;
- if some adjectives come after the noun in your native language, then those adjectives will come before the noun in English, but after other adjectives coming befor the noun in both languages;
- if in the adjectives coming after the noun in your native language, colour adjectives come last, then reverse the order of those adjectives in English.

The first rule means you could actually end up with variations of the sort "an elderly single mother" or "a single elderly mother" depending on which colloquation is intended.

The last rule covers some cases where adjectives following the noun can allow a "reversed" order or not, e.g. Rowlett (2007) cites French examples: "une jolie petite jupe [bleue fleurie écossaise']", which also permits "...[écossaise fleurie bleue]", with English "A pretty little blue floral Scottish skirt".

This goes for adjectives that are actually adjectives, incidentally: it isn't necessarily valid to class determiners, quantifiers, adverbs and nouns inside compounds as adjectives, for example (one of the links above appears to, and I think this could confuse the issue).

It should also be noted that we're talking about the unmarked order; for emphasis, the 'emphasised' adjectives can generally be placed before all others even if that means that it's out of place ("There are lots of cheap lawnmowers, but this is an OLD cheap lawnmower").

If you start giving actual lists of orderings (which, as I say, may be universal anyway), there is a danger in assuming that the order that applies with, say, nouns denoting tangible objects will then apply to nouns denoting emotions or actions.