# Ordering of multiple, consecutive adjectives

Tags: adjectives, word-order, lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adjective order](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/adjective-order)

One a comedy show, one of the comedians was a female who was black and from the UK. The host introduced her as a the first *black, female, British comedian* he has had on the show.

On a package of salmon, the label read *Smoked Norwegian Steelhead Salmon*. (There were no commas because it was a package—commas are necessary in prose though right?)

When using multiple, consecutive adjectives for a noun, is there a rule of thumb (or even hard and fast rule) for ordering of the adjectives? A reasonable theory is that it should go from least to most specific, but since English tends to do things in reverse, it would go the other way around. That fits for the salmon, but not the comedienne’s list, yet both feel natural.