# Passive clauses without auxiliaries

Tags: word-order, passive-voice

Sentences such as *I came across a letter that was typed by her secretary,* can be "reduced" by removing *that* and the auxiliary verb, yielding *I came across a letter typed by her secretary.* In this particular case, the *by* phrase, or some other modifying phrase such as *that morning* or *in red ink* appears to be obligatory. You can't simply say, **I came across a letter typed,* although you can say *I came across a typed letter.*

In other cases, though, this seems to be OK; consider *All the students arrested were from King's College.*

In what cases is a dependent required to make the clause grammatical? Can anyone point me to a discussion of this in a reliable reference grammar, preferably the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language?* I see it mentioned there on p. 78, but this particular issue is not discussed.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30223/superlative-noun-possible-why-does-the-adjective-come-after-the-noun

Comment: However, the following is OK: "This letter[,] typed[,] looks much better than when it was handwritten." I'd recommend that any answer address why. (Sorry, I just saw that this question is over a decade old . . .)

Comment: I will read it tomorrow. I am  so knackered if I read it now, I don't think I will understand anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I came across a letter that was typed.

The Original Poster notes that the relative clause in this sentence doesn’t seem to able to be “reduced” and that you can’t simply say **I came across a letter typed*, although you can say *I came across a typed letter.*

The word *typed* in (1) seems to refer to the state of the letter, its medium. Notice that we could change the word *was* for the word *looked* here without changing the sense of this word:

2. I came across a letter that looked typed.

These three facts—that the word *typed* seems to refer to the then state of the letter; that it can precede the noun *letter*, but not follow it; that it can function as the complement of the verb *looked*—show that this word is an adjective, not a verb.

Some verbs describe states or situations, whilst others describe actions or events. We call the latter *dynamic* verbs. The adjectives derived from the past participles of verbs, however, always refer to states, regardless of the meaning of the original verb (See *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, henceforth CGEL, pp. 1437-1439). *Type* is a verb with a dynamic meaning: typing is a clatterous affair, especially if done on a typewriter. The fact that *typed* in (1) has a stative interpretation shows it to be an adjective.

Secondly, setting aside the special case of never-attributive adjectives, adjective phrases which don’t contain  any material after the adjective must usually precede the nouns they modify (CGEL, p. 445). Adjective phrases containing material after the adjective must follow a noun they modify :

3. a **huge** mouse / *a mouse **huge**
4. *a **worried about her patient** doctor/a doctor **worried about her patient**.

For this reason, the relative clause in (1) cannot be “reduced” because this would result in an ungrammatical [noun + single adjective] sequence. More generally, then, we cannot “reduce” relative clauses where the complement of the deleted *be* is a single adjective. It’s worth noticing, in passing, that we cannot reduce relative clauses if the complement of the verb *be* is a noun phrase. Compare *I came across a man who was a doctor* and **I came across a man a doctor*.

Thirdly, the verbs *seem, look, appear, remain* and *become* can take adjectives as complements, but not participle verbs (CGEL p. 79):

7. *Bob looks smiling / Bob looks interesting
8. *The apples seemed eaten with gusto / The apples seemed rotten.

One further piece of evidence here is that if the speaker still has the letter referred to in (1), she might pull it out and say:

9. Look!  This letter is typed.

… where the word *typed* seems to have the same meaning as it has in (1). If *typed* was a verb referring to the typing event, as opposed to an adjective referring to the medium of the letter,  we would expect *was* not *is* here.

However, although this is by far and away the most likely reading of (1), it is at least technically possible that the relative clause contains a past simple, passive construction with *was* as a passive auxiliary and *typed* as a past participle verb. The problem is that it is difficult to find a context where this would be a pragmatically felicitous utterance. Integrated relative clauses tend to be used to enable listeners to pick out identifiable objects or people, or to describe an integral attribute or property of the denotee of the noun. The idiom *came across* indicates that the speaker just happened to encounter the letter, and the indefinite article, *a*, indicates the listener will not recognise which letter the speaker is talking about. It also implies that the letter has not been mentioned in the previous discourse. It is difficult to understand why the speaker would make direct reference to the  typing action or event, which they presumably did not witness. If, however, you could find a context in which such a reading of (1) was felicitous, you *would* be able to “reduce” the clause to just a single past participle verb, *typed*.

We can try to contrive an example where such a reading of (1) might be felicitous. However, it should be understood that whether this works or not makes no difference to the general point that you can “reduce” a relative clause to a single past participle verb. Here goes:

- The secretarial pool had had a marathon typing session the previous day churning out letters for MPs. The next day in the mail room, I came across a letter which was typed, and noticed that not only was it full of spelling mistakes, …

If that strikes you as pragmatically felicitous then so should the version with the “reduced” clause:

- The secretarial pool had had a marathon typing session the previous day churning out letters for MPs. The next day in the mail room, I came across a letter typed, and noticed that not only was it full of spelling mistakes, …

**The Original Poster’s Question**

The essence of the original question is: When can we reduce integrated relative clauses to just one *-ed* word? The answer is that we can normally “reduce” the clause if the *-ed* word is a verb, but not if it is an adjective.

As described in CGEL on p.78, and in several other places, participle clauses can freely be used to postmodify nouns. They don’t mention any special restrictions on participle clauses consisting  of just one word, mainly because there aren’t any. However, in the same way that several factors may affect the felicity of an integrated relative clause, the same is true of participle clauses used to modify nouns. If the original relative clause is felicitous, so will the "reduced" clause be.

It is perfectly fine, therefore, to “reduce” a relative clause to leave a single past participle, *typed*:

- A letter that was typed was a dollar that was  earned.
- A letter  typed was a dollar  earned.
- All letters that are typed must be vetted by the head secretary.
- All letters typed must be vetted by the head secretary.
- We pay £20 for every letter that  is  typed.
- We pay £20 for every letter typed.

Comment: Isn't *printed* / *handwritten* in "a letter printed/handwritten,..." the end result of an action? "I came across a letter, yellow, and realised it was from my father." doesn't make sense unless we imply its aged appearance  "I came across a letter, yellowed, and realised... "

Comment: I had to reread this answer and then read all the other answers for the first time. You and Greybeard are basically saying, if *typed* is clearly a verb then a sentence can end with a PP.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you take a dynamic verb, whilst the past participle describes the action, the adjective described the state of something after the action happened to it. "I heard a crashing sound as the window was broken"= verb "broken". "Don't touch the window, it's broken"=adjective. Notice that the adjective there describes the current state of the window but, as you say, entails that there was an earlier window-breaking event.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "You and Greybeard are basically saying, if typed is clearly a verb then a sentence can end with a PP" <-- Not quite. You can end a sentence with a P-P or an adjective, no problem. But you can't (usually) postmodify a noun with a single adjective, and you can't "reduce a RC to a single adjective. Greybeard says that in "a letter typed", the word "typed" is a depictive adjective. My post says it could only be a verb. It's a bit early in the morning for grammar! ;-)

Comment: Greybeard's answer towards the end says: *it does not hinder the understanding of **"typed"** as a verb as the listener reader will recognise a passive.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, the post contradicts itself a bit! Earlier it says *Here, typed is a depictive adjective* and also "In *I came across a typed letter*, from the syntax, *typed* is clearly functioning as an adjective." And then later it says that to make *typed* a verb in *I came across a letter typed* you can add *that is*. (But, actually,  if you add *that is* it could now be an adjective, whereas it couldn't without it!). I don't really understand where that post stands. (shrugs)

Answer (score 6):

In both of your sentences, what you have is the passive participle *typed*, which syntactically functions as a noun modifier. When *typed* is being used alone, it follows the normal rules for modifier placement and precedes the noun:

> I found a **typed** letter.

However, as a passive participle *typed* is able to take an adverbial complement that specifies the agent. When this occurs, the entire phrase must then follow the noun.

> I found a letter **typed by the secretary**.

This rule is not unique to passive participles: in general, English requires single-word modifiers to precede a noun, but multi-word modifiers to follow the noun. (The exact rules are fairly complex, but the preceding rule of thumb covers the most common cases.) You can see the same thing with active participles ending in *-ing* and ordinary adjectives.

> I saw a **red** ball.
>
> I saw a ball **red as the rising sun**.
>
> I met a **dying** man.
>
> I met a man **dying of AIDS**.

I don't have a copy of the CGEL to refer to, but if you look up the section on adjective and adjective phrases I'm sure you'll find a discussion of adjectival word order.

Comment: I object to adjective as a function, (it's a category; the function is modifier) but I take your meaning.

Comment: @Brett, you're right. I updated the answer to reflect that terminology, since it's more accurate.

Comment: Repetition of my answer? Ok, so it was formatted nicer.

Comment: Hang on! What about *All the students arrested were from King's College*?

Comment: @Brett, like I said, the full rules are more complex than that.

Comment: I'd like to hear about the complexities. And I spent about half an hour with CGEL and couldn't find anything that addresses this.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this pattern also exists for the verb *to be*: *the man who is tall* becomes *the tall man* whereas *the man who is in the room* becomes *the man in the room*.

I think the answer to your question lies in the rules for adjectives which follow the nouns that they modify. These reduced adjective clauses are, for all purposes, adjectives themselves and when they are reduced to a single word, they are positioned as a normal adjective, that is before the noun. However they follow the noun when they have more than one word after being reduced, just as with other multiple word adjectives in English (except hyphenated adjectives).

For example, you can't say *He has a black as the night soul* but you can say *He has a soul black as the night*. The adjective phrase *black as the night* follows the noun *soul* because it is a phrase not a single word.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not convinced you can't ever put as "extended ajectival clause" before the noun. Bad example, perhaps, and it does kinda need quote marks, but I don't have a problem with *I'd rather buy a "Made in Britain" product*.

Comment: That one seems like a bit of a stretch to me. I guess I'd argue that "Made in Britain" acts as a single adjective that modifies the noun. But I'd never use it as you just did.

Comment: Well, **"to die for clothes"** gets a lot of [google hits](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&source=hp&q=%22to+die+for+clothes%22&pbx=1&oq=%22to+die+for+clothes%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l12l184312l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=2ce18aafd4b76dc6&biw=1137&bih=741). I'm not in the least fashion-concious, but I don't see that one as odd. Although obviously many people do - apart from the ones who put it in quotes as per my first example, quite a few instances feel the need to replace one or both spaces with hyphens.

Comment: It took me a couple of moments to parse *to die for clothes* as an adjective-noun combination! I agree with you on this one though. To me, it seems acceptable as well. The exceptions aside, I think we can still say that in general non-hyphenated multi-word adjectives follow the noun they modify.

Answer (score 2):

> You can't simply say, **I came across a letter typed*,

This is not so.

*“As I went through his correspondence, the letters were all handwritten until I came across a letter typed.”* Here, *typed* is a depictive adjective. The sentence equates to “*I came across a letter and it was typed.*”

In *I came across a typed letter*, from the syntax, typed* is clearly functioning as an adjective.

It is the distinction between adjective and verb that has to be maintained in order to express an idea clearly.

In *I came across a letter [that was] typed by her secretary*, compared to *I came across a letter typed.” you will notice two things:

1 The lack of an agent in the latter.

2 Except for the depictive reading, the natural reading of the latter goes to understanding of *“typed”* as a postpositional common adjective but, because of standard syntax, it is non-standard/not idiomatic here.

With the disappearance of clear grammatical cases, syntax took on a crucial role in English.

In *I came across a letter [that was] typed by her secretary*, *typed* **must** be understood as a past participle – a verb. This can be done by

3 including “that was” and/or

4. including “by her secretary”, which is adverbial. However this is not essential to the understanding, as adverbs may qualify verbs or adjectives, but it does not hinder the understanding of "**typed**" as a verb as the listener reader will recognise a passive.

Now consider

*I came across the number of species that were seen/recorded by the members.*

*I came across the number of species seen/recorded by the members.*

*I came across the number of species seen/recorded.*

*I came across the number of seen/recorded species.*

Answer (score 1):

The reason Huddleston and Pullum don’t discuss it is perhaps that it is as at least as much a semantic question as a grammatical one. *Typing* is a process and, as such, not something you just *come across*. Moreover, a mundane process such as typing is not one you would normally want to comment on unless you wanted to draw attention to the fact that it **was** *typed by her secretary*, or *typed that morning* or *typed in red ink*. By contrast, it would be quite reasonable to say *I have seen a jet engine assembled* because that is something you *see* rather than *come across*, and it is sufficiently out of the ordinary to report for its own sake.

Comment: The *jet engine assembled* example is a different construction. There *assembled* is a complement of *seen*, not a modifier of *engine*.