# I found an unusual usage of adj, please tell me how it works

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, whiz-deletion

> Following the terror attacks in London on July 7, 2005, the then Prime Minister Tony Blair insisted those responsible were motivated by an "evil ideology," ...

From CNN. It uses *those responsible*; I searched on the Internet and found out that *responsible* is not a noun but an adjective. Can anybody tell me how to use such an expression?

Comment: read: "those (who are) responsible" -- ellipsis. HTH.

Comment: When Blair said this he was breaking with a custom which had been established in Britain during the Irish *troubles*. Back in the seventies news reporters used to say, after some bombing atrocity in which people had been killed, things like *The I.R.A./Loyalist Paramilitaries claimed responsibility for the incident*. It was felt that the word 'responsibility' tended to put a cloak of respectability on what had been a cowardly and heinous act. So the BBC and other media started saying simply 'The IRA/ Loyalists said *they did it*. The BBC continue such policy with current Middle East murders,

Answer (score 6):

(Almost) any adjective can be turned into a noun by putting *the* or a demonstrative pronoun (like *those*) before it, or another determiner (like *all*).  In most cases, the result means "those people who are [adjective]".

> those responsible = those who are responsible
>
> the weak = people who are weak
>
> all responsible = all who are responsible

In many cases, only some determiners are possible, depending on the adjective and the context; and some determiners may be more or less likely to be used than others, result in a different meaning depending on context, etc.

> the possible (e.g. "what which is possible")
>
> ?all possible (I can't think of a context that would allow this)
>
> those possible ("those things that are possible")
>
> ?the hot
>
> ?all hot
>
> those hot enough ("those things that are hot enough"; less likely without a modifier)

When the adjective is unfit to describe people, either in context or intrinsically, adding *the* usually results in a meaning such as "the x-ness, the x aspect", or basically anything that would make sense elliptically. When talking about wires, "the red" refers to the red wire.  It should be noted that adding *the* to such an adjective usually makes it singular, as opposed to "people adjectives" above.

Of course *those* does always result in a plural. When talking about tools, *those available* refers to those tools that are available. But, again, in many cases many determiners are impossible, especially *the*. In such cases, it usually becomes *(all) the x one(s)*.

There is a connexion with [adjectives that can come after their nouns in general](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/30310/3036), such as *available* (*those tools available*): such adjectives are more likely to allow determiners even if they are unfit for describing people. There is something that makes those adjectives more predicative, and predicative adjectives don't come before their nouns.

Comment: I think it needs pointing out that with a few exceptions (the opposite...), only adjectives which modify nouns with human referents are likely to be used as nominal adjectives (*the/all/those... canine // * the nuclear // *the silvery ...), and that 'the' won't often work (*the responsible // *the hot // *the too hot ...) and sometimes neither will other determiners (*those hot) without padding (those too hot to continue working inside).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: All good points. I have incorporated most of them; edit away where you see room for improvement.

Comment: Another common way to say this is to use the word "one" at the end. To my ear, "The hot one" is more common that "the hot", although in "those responsible ones", the "ones" is correct but unnecessary, and would generally not be said.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham:I've added a note about *one(s)*, which is indeed the most important complement.

Comment: The examples not involving 'the' (your first and third, and OP's) are readily explained by whiz-deletion as you show. [John Lawler's explanations](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121615/passive-vs-active-or-omission-of-which-is/121619#121619) are probably a preduplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Responsible is an adjective. This sentence is saying that the people that were responsible for the terror attacks in London were motivated by an "evil ideology". When using responsible in the first-person, i.e. *I am responsible*, you are either saying that you are trustworthy and mature or you are saying that you are the person that did the thing in a certain situation or that you are chargeable with being the author or cause of something. Just replace *those* in *those responsible* with the words *the ones that were* or *the people that were*.