# "in America in the 21st century" or "in the 21st century in America"

Tags: word-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Royal Order of Adverbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79547/the-royal-order-of-adverbs)

Which of the following sentence is correct?

> – No child should grow up in poverty *in America in the 21st century*.
>
> – No child should grow up in poverty *in the 21st century in America*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Royal Order of Adverbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79547/the-royal-order-of-adverbs); and for adjectives, see [What is the rule for adjective order?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155),

Comment: Quibble: “Which sentence is correct” is off-topic or too broad to be answered.  For example, it opens up the possibility of debate of the premise that children in poverty should not be allowed to grow up.

Comment: or "No child should grow up in poverty in 21st century America".