# I'd like to know Noun + past participle

Tags: past-tense, participles

*I want to come home more relaxed.*

I'd like to know, why *more relaxed* comes after *home* if it modifies *home*. Or can *more relaxed* in this sentence be used as an adverb?

Comment: Consider that _come home_ means 'arrive'; would _I want to arrive more relaxed_ pose a grammatical problem? _More relaxed_ does NOT modify _home_ here; it refers to (but does not modify) the subject _I_ and indicates that _I want (to be) more relaxed_.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Thank you for your question. You may also want to look into the difference between "co-operation" and "corporation" ;)

Comment: This is an opinion - stated mostly so others will check it and tell me why if I am wrong. // I think both 'home' and 'more relaxed' are adverbs modifying 'come', one defines place and the other manner. // The typical order (aka Royal Order) is **manner, place, time** [see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79547/the-royal-order-of-adverbs] // The order here is place then manner // The typical order is not a rule, it's merely an observation of what usually sounds most natural. // In your sentence, the order which sounds natural is the opposite. // There is no reason why. It just is.

Comment: All of your answers make sense to me!