# Order of several adverbs of the same type

Tags: adverbs

Today I started an English course with a new teacher. After being asked to arrange words into a proper sentence, she pointed me out on being wrong on something: I said "tomorrow at six", and she said that i should always say "at six tomorrow". I questioned why, and her answer was that the order of adverbs of a single type should be the specificity. The same rule would apply to "In my living room on the couch", where it would be incorrect and the correct form would be "On the couch in my living room". Another example where I would be wrong would be something along the lines of "Next week on Friday at six", the correct form would be "At six on Friday next week", no other forms would be correct.

I had never heard of this rule before despite using both ways quite often. Our English teaching material also showed this and explicitly said it's a rule, however i could not find a single mention of this outside of our specific material, and after asking around from some British friends, they said that the rule was nonsense. I would like a clear answer on this and if possible, something to cite as well.

I had a previous English teacher who i proved wrong on some conditional stuff that she was teaching wrong before as well, the quality control around here is not the greatest, though if I am wrong then please point me out on it, I want to learn. Is this an actual rule, just preference, or completely nonsense? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I appreciate the linking of https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Order-of-Adverbs.htm, which cites the same information as present in our material. However this seems less like a set in stone rule and more like a rule of thumb for when in doubt. Am I correct on this? Again i can't find anything about this in stuff like https://www.uop.edu.jo/download/research/members/oxford_guide_to_english_grammar.pdf. Thanks!

Edit2: In the examples given in the aforementioned link using other arrangements sounds unnatural as well, which would be understandable. However there are a lot of cases where both seem just fine, at least to me.

Comment: Is this English as a foreign language, or is it high school in an English speaking curriculum? Either way 'tomorrow at six' is how I would say it. 'Correct' is a strange word to use here - it might be a suggested style by that teacher (but I personally don't see anything in these two examples where any order really is better than the other).

Comment: As i said before, this was said to be a rule by my teacher, and looking at our teaching material it is also explicitly said. The schooling system here is a bit different than most places (from Finland), so i guess this would equate to about grade 10 in the US. Translating what is said in our material to English: "Should we have many adverbials of the same type, they are arranged by specificity". You can't understand the text in this link, but you can see the examples: https://i.imgur.com/doamKir.png

Comment: There have been lists of rules drawn up for the ordering of adverbs, and your teacher is mentioning a _reasonably_ accurate rule of thumb, but it doesn't work in this particular case. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+six+tomorrow%2Ctomorrow+at+six&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20six%20tomorrow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctomorrow%20at%20six%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cat%20six%20tomorrow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctomorrow%20at%20six%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggest that both probably used almost equally frequently (as @Mitch and I concur).

Comment: I'd look for a different course. Your teacher is ***seriously*** ill-equipped to be teaching English.

Comment: thank you for the answers everyone. Unfortunately due to how the school is structured, I have to take her course as the 2nd English course, which is mandatory. I will bring this up after next class though. I will make sure to have a different teacher for the rest of the courses, since my teacher for the first one was excellent and even complimented me on pointing out stuff i thought was badly made in our material. //Edit; accidental enter lol

Comment: These things are tricky and, as you suggest, often style choices. For instance, I'd usually stick 'pm' on "Next week on Friday at four", but wouldn't with 'tomorrow at four', even though the 'pm' is hardly necessary for disambiguation here. One gets a feel for certain cadences after 60+ years of speaking a language. Of course, in the southern USA, people often get settled with different preferences. I'd use "In the living room on the sofa" normally, as that's the way someone's going to find their way to my new magazine. But the other way would be appropriate in other contexts – for ...

Comment: instance in the context "Your new 'Model Collector' magazine isn't on the sofa in the hall." ...    "It's on the sofa _in the living room_."  (Not that we actually have a hall that big.)

Comment: I see what you mean. Should be noted that my whole point was that neither are incorrect and especially when referring to adverbs of time it shouldn't really matter what is used, because both sound fine to me. Of course if there is something I'm missing then point it out.

Comment: Also I feel like this should be noted: The teaching material we use is used in basically every upper secondary school in Finland...

Comment: There are thesis-level articles on the ordering of adverbs. Rule-making attempts (for rules that always apply) become farcical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Royal Order of Adverbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79547/the-royal-order-of-adverbs) (where there's an answer to which I've added an extension covering 'multiple adverbs of the same category').

Comment: I wonder what the rule/style is on other languages. How about in Finnish?