# Is the phrase "fresh six muffins" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, word-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

A non-native speaker that I know always puts the count before another adjective, as in "fresh six muffins". "Six fresh muffins" seems to be more grammatically correct.

This sounds so funny. It seems that there is a rule that the number must come before any other adjectives.

Is there a hierarchy of adjectives and rules that determine which ones come first?

Is there any logic to these rules?