# Adjective order convention

Tags: adjectives, word-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

As a native speaker, I would always say "big red ball," but never "red big ball."

Further, I would say "Big red furry ball," and not ever another order of adjectives.

Is there a *correct*, or *accepted* order/precedence of adjectives?

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1155