# Adjective order: Why is "big" before "beautiful"?

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, word-order, commas

I was reading an English children story to my niece the other day when I came across these phrases said by three different characters:

> - I want a big, beautiful hat!
> - I want a big, exciting computer!
> - I want a big, expensive TV!

Why is the first adjective *big* and not the adjective expressing an evaluation or opinion? I thought adjectives expressing the speaker's opinion came first and foremost. I am also curious about the comma separating the two adjectives, how does it affect meaning?

And finally, if I were to insert *red* in the first example, where would it fit best and should I keep the commas?

> *I want a big, beautiful red hat!
>
>   I want a beautiful, big red hat!
>
>   I want a big, red, beautiful hat!*

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the rule for adjective order?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

Comment: And as for your second question: [When should an adjective be followed by a comma?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128256/when-should-an-adjective-be-followed-by-a-comma)

Comment: I want a big truck. I want a beautiful big truck. I want to grow huge broccoli. I want to grow beautiful huge broccoli. I want a gigantic wedding. I want beautiful gigantic wedding.

Comment: Per the [*accepted*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/56874/2637) (but not *most-upvoted*) answer to what I think is the "original" question for which this is a duplicate, an adjective which is ***evaluational*** normally comes ***first***. By implication, if the most important characteristic you seek in your "red hat" is that it should be "big", that comes first. If you're more concerned that it should be "beautiful", you'd specify *that* word first.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that the most important quality comes first.  Big used first sounds more like a generic "great", and therefore not really about size as much as it is about awesomeness, although it couldn't be about something small. When it's used next to the noun, it's more about the size.  "Big beautiful hat" is different from "beautiful big hat"; the latter must be a big hat, whereas the former can big or medium, just not small. Likewise, "big expensive TV" is different from "expensive big TV"; the latter sounds to me like it would take up most of the wall.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I appreciate that the "What is the rule for adjective order" apparently answers my question, but it doesn't. Believe me when I say, I looked at that question and the answers before asking mine. I'm usually careful not to repeat questions which have already been asked. In this specific case I am not asking for the rule, I am asking *why* "big" comes before beautiful, exciting, and expensive and *why* it is followed by a comma. If I were to follow the royal order than SpeedyGonzalez's answer would be the correct one and I would have upvoted his, but I didn't. Cont'd.

Comment: Likewise your saying the most important feature should come first, doesn't ring true for me. What if *red* was the most important characteristic? Women more than men, are usually more concerned with items or clothings which match in colour. Should I say: **"I want a red, big beautiful hat"**? I *could* if I really wanted to but that order sounds off. Perhaps if I said: "Above all, I want a red hat that matches my shoes, it must also be big and extremely beautiful." Then my priority would be crystal clear. Personally, I think Shoe's answer is the best so far.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Well, hopefully you realise that the "rule" is at best a "guide". If you check all permutations of *beautiful big red* in Google Books you'll see that the overwhelming majority are in that order, conforming to the general guidelines. But suppose you went in the hat shop (wearing those shiny red shoes [which I know you have!](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/has-anyone-on-elu-been-awarded-the-i-see-your-point-hat-yet#comment14622_4382) :), and said *"I'm looking for a beautiful big hat!"* ...

Comment: ... Further suppose the milliner didn't even *think* about those shoes, so he brought out various "beautiful big hats" for you to consider, but none in the all-important red. You could just point out that you wanted a "beautiful big *red* hat", and let vocal stress carry the emphasis. But you might well ***also*** promote "red" to the *front* of the list. It wouldn't sound weird in such a context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I do like your comment, and I think you have explained very well that the royal order of adjectives is but a useful guideline, and I agree when speaking we stress on the words which we consider are most relevant, or help clarify intention and meaning. And I congratulate you on your memory, I am most impressed!

Comment: @Mari-Lou: My memory wasn't that good. I would have bet money the original reference was to *"**shiny** red shoes"*, so that was the quoted string I gave Google for a site-specific search term. Fortunately, although it didn't find the *quoted* string, it did put your previous comment at the top of the "close matches" list. (Oh - and did I forget to mention that I have a fetish about shiny red shoes! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commas between adjectives are typically used for adjectives from the same category:

> That was a very expensive, boring, useless conference. *(Opinion
>   adjectives)*
>
> ?That was a very expensive boring useless conference.

Adjectives from different categories are not usually separated by commas:

> She's just bought a beautiful new red car.

However, writers may separate words from different categories with commas, and reorder them, in order to give each word individually a focus that it would not have in a non-comma-separated list. This is what is happening with sentences such as:

> I want a big, red, beautiful hat!

Answer (score 3):

Generally, adjectives of quantity and size precede others. I can't say why, except that was how it was ordered in Latin.

> I want *many*  *big*  *beautiful*  *soft*  *red*  *silk*  hats. No commas.

Color and material are subset adjectives, and for that reason usually goes right before the *set* (hats) it modifies.

You don't need commas unless the adjectives don't modify each other.

> I want *many*  *big*  *beautiful*  *soft*  *red, green, purple and yellow* silk hats.

How do you know if an adjective modifies another? Try using *and* between them. *Red* and *green* and *purple* and *yellow* doesn't change the meaning of the words, so they are "equal" (and get commas), but if you want a *purplish green striped yellow spotted red* hat, meaning changes with *and*, so you must order them the way you want them. A purplish-green striped, yellow-spotted (comma optional) red hat. (Does that make sense?)

Oh, in the time I typed this, others have given better answers, so I'll stop here.

Please know that the order of adjectives is still being debated.

This is one ordering I've found.

evaluation > size > shape > condition > human propensity > age > color >     origin > material + attributive noun.

I myself would change this to number > size > evaluation > shape...

(French takes almost this order, I think, with the subsets following the noun. Je veux beaucoup de beaux grands chapeaux de soie rouge. I like the word "de". Less complicated.)

Oh, and, as in Latin, the order can be changed to emphasize or differentiate.

Comment: Very interesting ideas here. One more important one is that the order has to 'sound right'. That only comes from years of listening.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the correct answer should be:

> I want a  beautiful big red hat.

There is rule about the order of adjectives:

1.General opinion
2.Specific opinion
3.Size
4.Shape
5.Age
6.Colour
7.Nationality
8.Material

I don't think commas are needed. Here is one nice chart:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I have a list of requirements or desiderata, I put the most important one first, as it is the one people are most likely to remember. So a *big, beautiful, red hat* must first and foremost be *big*, whereas its being *beautiful* is highly desirable, and it should be *red* if possible.

Comment: Why would you add a comma after *beautiful*? I think the phrase: "A beautiful red hat" sounds acceptable without a comma. Could one write: "A beautiful, red hat"? Moreover, it seems to me that *red hat* is an essential requisite.

Comment: I disagree with your listing by requirement. It is quite awkward to say, e.g. I want moire, red, four, silk, big hats, simply because you desire them in that order. Furthermore, everyone reading that list **will** (besides being confused) assume that it is first and foremost four red moire silk (or silk moire) hats that you want.