# order of adjectives exceptions

Tags: adjectives

Which is correct "A huge unattractive block of flats" or "An unattractive huge block of flats". What is the word "huge" - an opinion or a size?

Comment: Please see [What is the rule for adjective order?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

Comment: which do you think? What are some synonyms for *huge*. Are they an opinion?

Comment: related: [Adjective order. Why is "big" before "beautiful"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145041/adjective-order-why-is-big-before-beautiful)

Answer (score 1):

[Google Books Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=huge%20ugly%20building%2Chuge%20unattractive%20building%2Cbig%20ugly%20building%2Cugly%20big%20building&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chuge%20ugly%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbig%20ugly%20building%3B%2Cc0) comes to the rescue, and suggests that the following phrases: "huge unattractive building" and a simpler version "ugly big building" are not recorded. On the other hand, *[big ugly building](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22big%20ugly%20building%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)* and *[huge ugly building](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22huge%20ugly%20building%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)* are both cited.

[image: Google NGram showing that 'huge unattractive building' and 'ugly big building' are not found.]

This doesn't exclude the possibility of using the adjective *unattractive* to describe a *block of flats* or an *apartment building* (AmEng), it's just less common, and rarely used in conjunction with other adjectives.

[image: Google NGram of American English starting in 1960 showing much higher use of 'ugly building' than 'unattractive' building.]

Answer (score -1):

In both the sentences, huge should be acting as an adjective for the block of flats (being used as a second adjective). However, in the first sentence, if you want to use "huge" as an opinion, use "hugely" and it will act as an adverb for the word 'unattractive'.

Comment: Never knew that *huge* is also an adverb.