# What is the term for this sort of ambiguity?

Tags: single-word-requests, ambiguity, humor, headline-english

"**Scientists discover emperor penguin colony in Antarctica using satellite images**"

This is the title of an [article in the Guardian newspaper](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2023/jan/20/scientists-discover-emperor-penguin-colony-in-antarctica-using-satellite-images) today.

There must be some clever penguins down there?

I appreciate that this is *ambiguous* because of a slip in arrangement, but it is only truly ambiguous if the reader knows nothing about penguins. Otherwise the meaning is clear from the subject matter and the context, even if amusing. Hence the ambiguity is of a restricted sort.

I have searched synonyms of ambiguity in Merriam Webster and Thesaurus but find no term to fit this limited type. Can anyone suggest a suitable word or phrase please?

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambiguity)
> *ambiguity*:
> a word or expression that can be understood in two or more possible ways : an ambiguous word or expression

Comment: related: [Explain the phrase "Old Norwegian History Professor" and provide other examples](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128676/) and ["How do you solve a problem like Maria?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507640/) and [What is the name of the ambiguity in the phrase "I want to visit clubs with attractive women"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120300/)

Comment: **MODERATOR WARNING: *Do not open duplicate questions.*** We do not open duplicate questions just because the duplicate is older than a preschool child. We do not open duplicate questions just because you don't like existing answers. We have other ways to attract attention on existing questions.