# Which noun does an Adjective associate with of

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives

I read the [Adjective Association question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149379/adjective-association) but I'm wondering how it applies to the following sentence:

> Here is a really old picture of me.

It appears that *really old*, and *picture* are associated to *me*, but it could also be assumed that *really old* associated to *picture*.  Seems ambiguous.

Slightly changing the sentence:

> Here is a blurry old picture of me.

Seems to indicate the picture, whereas I cannot come up with an adjective that would associate to *me* (might exist).

Comment: I don't see how you can say *really old* in #1 "associates" with *me*. If I say *"Here's a really old picture of the king"* surely it's obvious the thing which is "really old" is the *picture*, not the *king*. It would be completely different if I said *"Here's a picture of the really old king"*. In both of your examples, "of me" simply qualifies the picture - in a different way to those adjectives that come *before* "picture", but also modify the same word.

Comment: [Picture nouns have many different possibilities](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/113916/15299) with possessives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is a really old picture of me.

The adjective in your sentence is *old*, and *really* is an adverb which modifies *old*. They are in their usual places - before the noun they modify.

*of me* can be dropped without changing the essential meaning of the adverb + adjective.

> Here is a really old picture.

If the adjective and adverb described *you*, and you are not really old, perhaps:

> Here is a photoshopped picture of me as really old.