# Order of adjectives in a sentence

Tags: adjectives, word-order

I'm making a website that has search results, and I hide some of them

I want to show the user that some are hidden

Which one should I say?

- Showing first 25 results only

or

- Showing 25 first results only

edit: I've seen questions like this [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order?rq=1)

But I was wondering what to do when you have 2 adjectives of the same kind. Or Perhaps "first" and "25" are not of the same type?

Comment: Have you tried searching for say "first 100 results" and "100 first results"?

Comment: Yeah and I results with both. I just wanted to see which one was the correct use.

Comment: @Pacane Just think it through logically. To begin with you need the definite article. 'The first 25 results' means results numbers 1 to 25. But 'the 25 first results', is a bit ambiguous and could imply that there were 25 things that were equal first.

Comment: @Pacane: I checked Google Books, but there weren't really enough ***results*** results to be conclusive. On the other hand, searching for ["the first 100 **applicants**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+first+100+applicants%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) yields 1250 results, as compared to ***none at all*** for ["the 100 first applicants"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+100+first+applicants%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). That should be a pretty big clue as to *what* people use (though *why* might be harder to answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Showing first 25 results only*

Is correct. You aren't showing the first result 25 times, you are showing the first 25 results one time.

Answer (score 0):

Just think it through logically. To begin with you need the definite article. 'The first 25 results' means results numbers 1 to 25. But 'the 25 first results', is a bit ambiguous and could imply that there were 25 things that were equal first.