# Are "white" and "black" ever capitalized when referring to people?

Tags: capitalization, political-correctness

What is the accepted custom regarding capitalization when it comes to "White" and "Black" when referring to race, whether they are being used as nouns or adjectives?

Comment: See the useful [historical overview](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=6722&p=51406) by Ken Greenwald (which is unfortunately too detailed to summarize in this posting) of the various designations that have been used for black people down the years.

Comment: On a personal basis, I capitalise both. As English has no authoritative body of overseers, there are no rules, only guidance.

Answer (score 19):

According to CMS, when referring to racial categories, use *whites* or *white people*, *blacks* or *black people*, both of which are written in lower case.

Chicago Manual of Style, 16th edition, 8.39, p. 402.

However, according to APA, racial and ethnic groups are designated by proper nouns and are capitalized: *Black* and *White.*

APA Publication Manual, 6th edition, 3.14, p. 75.

Therefore, follow the style guide used in whatever discipline or genre you are writing.

Comment: As I understand it, this has been revised and CMS now recommends capitalizing both Black and White. https://cmosshoptalk.com/2020/06/22/black-and-white-a-matter-of-capitalization/

Answer (score 3):

> Racial and ethnic groups are designated by proper nouns and are capitalized. Therefore, use *Black* and *White* instead of *black* and *white* (the use of colors to refer to other human beings is currently considered pejorative and should not be used). Unparallel designations (e.g., *African Americans* and *Whites*; *Asian Americans* and *Black Americans*) should be avoided because one group is described by color while the other group is described by cultural heritage (American Psychological Association 2012).

APA. (2012) Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association.

(Sixth edition). (p. 75) Washington, DC: American Psychological Association

Comment: Quotes must use some form of quote format (this time I fixed it for you). Other than that, this is a very relevant answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some news sources say they will capitalize "black", but not "white". Others capitalize both.

[AP says it will capitalize Black but not white](https://apnews.com/article/7e36c00c5af0436abc09e051261fff1f)

> Columbia Journalism Review, the Wall Street Journal, The New York
> Times, USA Today, the Los Angeles Times, NBC News and Chicago Tribune
> are among the organizations that have recently said they would
> capitalize Black but have not done so for white.
>
> “White doesn’t represent a shared culture and history in the way Black
> does,” The New York Times said on July 5 in explaining its decision.
>
> CNN, Fox News and The San Diego Union-Tribune said they will give
> white the uppercase, noting it was consistent with Black, Asian,
> Latino and other ethnic groups. Fox cited NABJ’s advice.
>
> CBS News said it would capitalize white, although not when referring
> to white supremacists, white nationalists or white privilege.

I personally think that the justification by the New York Times is absurd. If "white people" aren't a group, why are you even referring to it?

Comment: *AT THE COLUMBIA JOURNALISM REVIEW, [we capitalize Black, and not white, when referring to groups in racial, ethnic, or cultural terms](https://www.cjr.org/analysis/capital-b-black-styleguide.php). For many people, Black reflects a shared sense of identity and community. White carries a different set of meanings; capitalizing the word in this context risks following the lead of white supremacists.*

Answer (score 1):

It is a style issue. The *NYT* started doing it and then it was a thing. However, capitalizing Black and White and Brown is poor grammar. Simply, we only capitalize proper nouns in English.

**black, white, brown**

**African-American, Caucasian, Asian (among others)**

"African American" is going out of style possibly because so many black people are not African. Haitians in particular are modestly offended by the term.

Style is one thing, but bad grammar is against my good sense. I'm keeping it black, white, brown - at least until *Chicago* makes the change. The 17th Edition did not make a change, and the 18th is probably still a few years away.

Comment: Some style guides capitalize Black *because* they consider it a proper noun, as it represents a racial or ethnic group. Can you elaborate on why "Native American" is a properly capitalized proper noun, but "Black" is an improperly capitalized common noun? The argument at the end doesn't make much sense to me, as you suggest that this capitalization is non-grammatical, at least until your preferred *style guide* says otherwise, but style guides don't dictate grammar rules. Beyond that, capitalization isn't even a part of grammar - grammar arose *long before* written language was even invented.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Hey don't give ’em any funky ideas or pretty soon they really will demand that the grammar be changed, like by insisting that this capitalized color term be place right at the front of any string of adjectives, yielding *Native tall women, Black old men,* and [*Green great dragons*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56874/2085). :)

Comment: Style is style. The consideration of the nature of nouns and determining common versus proper is grammar. Or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Apparently, CMS *has* made the change? https://cmosshoptalk.com/2020/06/22/black-and-white-a-matter-of-capitalization/

Comment: Thank you. I'll be sure to write Yellow for my Southeast Asians. It sure is a lot closer to yellow than brown. And those with ichthiosis? Green people. Native Americans? Red people. It all makes sense now. Shivering people are Blue. I get it.