# Order of time from certain time to general time

Tags: prepositions, sentence-patterns

Here is the time order that I found quite confusing in a sentence, following with the sample sentence that I saw from a piece of teaching material:

The school party is on June 8th at 8 o'clock in the evening.

However, I wonder if it can be rewritten as the following?

> The school party is at 8 o'clock in the evening on June 8th

If not, may I know the rule of the order?

Comment: I wonder why you found it confusing? It seems common sense (in any language!) that readers need to know the date first (will I be free on  that day?) and the time second. No grammatical rule, just practicality.

Comment: Note that in your revised version it's possible to use a different preposition for the final element: *The school party is at 8 o'clock in the evening **of** June 8th*. That associates the object of the preposition (the date) with the preceding *noun* *(**evening**)* rather than being an adverbial element linking back to the main verb *(**is**)*. [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+morning+of+January%2Cin+the+morning+on+January&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) the relevant usage chart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The 'royal order of adverbs'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79547/the-royal-order-of-adverbs/79550#79550) (The article I quote looks at the rule of thumb for listing adverbs / adverbials of the same category (eg space, time) in order of increasing specificity. Or [Is there any rule of order for time, date, place, building, etc?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178620/is-there-any-rule-of-order-for-time-date-place-building-etc) (Austin Dean's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Both usages seem to be fairly common. If you search google for [`"at  * PM on * "`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22at++*+PM+on+*+%22) and [`"on * at * PM"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on+*+at+*+PM%22) You will get large number of hits for both (though former seems lot more popular than latter).

However, I think the order does have a significance. If you want to lay stress on the date , you put the date first. Otherwise, when the date or day is fairly well known (for instance a Sunday mass or an inaugural speech) the time is written first. Looking at some of the examples shown by google search might help. I don't know if a formal rule exists in this regard.

Comment: The ratio of usages, 69 : 72, is extremely near to unity as these things go (ie at first glance, equally commonly used). Of course, other pairings ('at 8 o'clock next Friday' '...', etc) may show different results. The availability of adding stress by choosing the order is a good point.

Comment: Searches for "at * o'clock last Monday" and "last Monday at * o'clock" seem to give remarkably similar results.