# What part-of-speech would a vehicle's year/make/model be?

Tags: adjectives, proper-nouns, parts-of-speech, compounds

Suppose I were to say this sentence: "I own a 2003 Ford F-150."

1. Would **2003 Ford F-150** be a compound proper noun?
2. Would **Ford F-150** be a compound proper noun and **2003** be an
   adjective?
3. Would **F-150** be a proper noun and **2003** and **Ford** be adjectives?
4. Am I way off, and there is some other term for this?

It's been a while since I've taken any sort of grammar course, so I'm admittedly rusty on some specific instances like this. I honestly don't think #3 is the correct answer, as Ford seems like it would definitely be part of the proper noun, but I included it just to be thorough.

Comment: When you have noun chains like those, each one but the last is an attributive noun, also called a noun adjunct.

Comment: @tchrist Looking at your profile, I see you are a programmer so I can probably explain further what prompted this question. I'm interested in this question because I'm trying to use it as an example to explain Object-Oriented Programming to someone. Typically for introductory examples, you use the noun = Object, adjective = Property, verb = Functions for illustration. I know it's not a perfect analogy but If I have 2003FordF150 extends FordF150, which extended Ford, which extended Vehicle would that make sense? Since properties could vary in different years of a vehicle.

Comment: You could consider asking on the Linguistics question site too.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks. I honestly never know where to post half of the questions I have on Stack Exchange. There seems to be a lot of redundancy.

Comment: @DavidStinemetze there is some redundancy, and that's not always a bad thing. Some questions have one home, some more than one, and some none. This question is fine here, but you might get different answers at the linguistics site. If you're satisfied with what you get here, don't bother asking there!

Comment: @curiousdannii I might do that in a bit.  I'm gonna let the discussion continue here for a little bit and see how it resolves.  I mean, for my purposes, I've got a sufficient of enough answer. At this point, I'm just curious what else others have to say about it.

Comment: All proper names are fixed phrases. Capitalization rules vary, but as long as they can be the subject or the object of a grammatical clause, fixed proper names are ***Noun Phrases***.

Comment: @JohnLawler So are you saying that the year would also be included in the Noun Phrase?

Comment: I'm saying you could include it in the proper noun phrase, or not, as you please; proper noun phrases are extremely individual and not subject to grammar rules. Or at least not to ordinary ones; they follow their own rules.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is there any where that this is documented as being the case? And if so would you post it as an answer?

Comment: Individual proper noun phrases are not "documented as being the case". Billions of them are spoken every day. As I said, rules vary for proper noun phrases, especially for written sentences. You pays your money and you takes your choice, just like everybody else.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well what I meant as "documented as being the case", was not referring to this specific instance.  What I mean is, is there some explicitly written rule that says something to the effect of "for proper noun phrases, all bets are off"?

Comment: Well, we both just wrote it here. That's explicitly written, and that's exactly what it says. What more do you want?

Comment: @JohnLawler My point is that I'm getting a lot of contradictory opinions in here, and I think having a reference to some sort of authoritative source would be ideal.

Comment: Well, pick your authority, then. What standards do **you** judge authorities by? Who has the right to tell you how you should talk and write? Be very very careful picking authorities.

Comment: If you were doing per-token part-of-speech assignments, *2003* would be classified as a [***numeral***, which is either its own word-class or a subclass of **determiner**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_(linguistics)).  Like other determiners, they [mandatorily precede all adjectives](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/56874) in the noun phrase. These are denoted by `CD` using [Penn Treebank tags](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) and by `crd` using [NUPOS tags](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/morphadorner/documentation/nupos/). (*cont...*)

Comment: (*in continuation*) However, here it’s part of a proper name, which all follow their own rules. Another example of a fixed numeral embedded in a proper name occurs at the end of *Queen Elizabeth II*, where this time the numeral a Roman one not an Arabic one the way *2003* is.  But you really have to think of these as inseparable entities w/1 POS tag. It’s not like *2003* or *Ford* — or *Queen* or *II* — are functioning as adjectives in support of some central noun in the noun phrase. The entire thing is a **multiword noun**, similar to how *West* is no adjective in *Morgantown, West Virginia*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"2003 Ford F-150" is a string of adjectives describing a truck. Trademarks are always adjectives, describing a noun by specifying its manufacturer or originator.

As the [International Trademark Association](http://www.inta.org/Pages/Home.aspx) puts it:

> Trademarks and service marks are proper **adjectives**. Not nouns. Not verbs. A mark should always be used as an adjective qualifying a generic noun that defines the product or service. A mark is a company brand name, not a product or service itself. -- [A Guide to Proper Trademark Use](http://www.inta.org/Media/Documents/2012_TMUseMediaInternetPublishing.pdf)

It's much clearer if you say "2003 Ford F-150 truck" that "truck" is the noun and the other words describe what kind of truck it is. But it's perfectly grammatical to omit the noun when it's clear from context what the noun is.

Comment: This seems to be the most definitive answer to me, given that this would definitely fall under the scope of a trademark. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

*Ford F-150* is the official full name of the car (make + model). Grammatically speaking, it is a compound proper noun:

> I own a Ford F-150.

*F-150* is an abbreviated version of that name:

> I own an F-150.

So is *Ford* in the following statement (although the designation could refer to any Ford motor car, not just an F-150):

> I own a Ford.

In your example sentence

> "I own a 2003 Ford F-150",

*2003* is an adjective; it is not a necessary element for specifying the *type* of car, but describes one of its *attributes* (namely its age).

Comment: Quick follow up question. There could be vast differences between  2003 and a 2014 making them two entirely different vehicles. Ordering parts for one versus the other can illustrate that.  Isn't the year key in identifying the product? To me it seems like 2003 says a lot more about the vehicle than "red" would. I guess I could be splitting hairs here, but I just figured I'd bring it up.

Comment: No, 2003 is a ***cardinal number***, which is something like a special subtype of noun — kinda.  It is certainly not an adjective. ***Ordinal numbers*** are more likely to be adjectives.

Comment: @DavidStinemetze - Let's assume for the sake of illustrating my point that the 2003 and 2014 models are vastly different from each other, but that model years 2003-2007 are all identical. The essence of the issue you have identified would then be that Ford has continued to use the same name for two completely different vehicles. So in my view, the model year remains an adjective (or *determiner*, to use the classification applied by many linguists) to describe the car's age, but the meaning of the compound noun *Ford F-150* is not the same when comparing a 2003 model to a 2014 model.

Comment: @tchrist - You're muddling up the different categories and uses of numbers. 2003 is a cardinal number if you're counting objects: *There are 2003 people in this theatre*. It's an ordinal number if you're specifying the position in a sequence: *That's the 2003rd time you've told me that*. When you're using it to describe the age of something, it's an adjective or determiner.

Comment: @tchrist Based on the definition of an ordinal number, it seems like that would be more accurate than cardinal number. 2003 would almost seem to indicate some sort of "version number". So instead of "first, second, third", it's just "two-thousand-third", or "two-thousand-fourteenth". Based on that it seems the classifying it as a "determiner" or at least as a special case should be good enough for my purposes.

Comment: Note that adjectives can be vital to determining the meaning of a sentence. Just because *2003* is an adjective (as I believe it is) does not mean it can be dismissed as unnecessary detail. *There goes my old lady* has a very different meaning without the adjective *old* in it. Adjectives can be key in identifying what exactly is being discussed.

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to call '2003' an adjective. It's function is a modifier, just like the function of adjectives, but that doesn't mean it is an adjective.

Comment: @curiousdannii - So what part of speech would you describe it as being?

Comment: @ErikKowal a numeral, possibly a noun.

Comment: It seems like it serves the same function as a color name, e.g. _red Ford F-150_.

Comment: @ErikKowal It can't really be a determiner because normal adjectives like *red* don't precede determiners: *red 2003 Fords* works, *red the Fords* doesn't*. Doesn't look like an adjective, can't grade it, for example (though could be other reasons for that).   Seems like a noun modifying a (proper) noun phrase to me.

Comment: @ErikKowal At this point I'm not exactly sure if I can accept this as the correct answer because there seems to still be some sort of dispute about it amongst people much more knowledgeable than I.  If you can either provide some sort of documented source to backup your answer, or modify the answer to include the dispute I can mark this answer correct.

Answer (score -1):

Ordinarily, if you're unsure about the part of speech for a portion of a sentence, a good place to start would be to try replacing the portion in question with a section whose POS is known *a priori*. In this case, both `2003` and `Ford` seem to be acting like adjectives--as people have mentioned, it feels fine to replace either word with `red` e.g. `red Ford F-150`, `2003 red F-150`--so the short answer is that in this case both `2003` and `Ford` are adjectives.

So, it turns out that all F-150s are Ford F-150s, so it feels like Ford is modifying the sentence in a different way than 2003 is, but I would argue that this is a problem of pragmatics, not syntax.

I would give a syntax tree of this sentence, using a simplified grammar, as

`I own a 2003 Ford F-150`

```
Sentence:
   Noun Phrase:
      Pronoun:
         "I"
   Verb Phrase:
      Transitive Verb:
         "own"
      Noun Phrase:
         Determiner:
            "a"
         Noun:
            Adjective:
               "2003"
            Noun:
               Adjective:
                  "Ford"
               Noun:
                  "F-150"
```

This analysis is backed up by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Compound_nouns) in their article on english compounds

Comment: But couldn't you also say "I drive a Ford" if there's context in the conversation where that would make sense? Or if there's enough context, "I drive a 2003".  That's not an adjective in these cases.

Comment: Absolutely. In English, nouns can act like adjectives "for free", without any morphological markings. Ford is usually a noun, but when it's used like this it's also an adjective. just like you can have an "office job" (a job in an office), or a "paper tray" (a tray for holding paper), you can have a "Ford truck" (a truck made by Ford)

Comment: @colinro Not really, when a noun modifies a noun it's still a noun, it doesn't become an adjective! You're right when you say that nouns can act like adjectives to the extent that they can have the same function, but they don't become a different part of speech. You can't for example say *yours is an officer job than mine*!

Comment: @Aruacaria I'm not sure I agree with you; you also can't say _yours is a red job than mine_, but nobody would take that as evidence that _red_ isn't an adjective

Comment: I’m sorry, but that parse is **pure nonsense.**  In a *“2003 Ford F-150”*, the *2003* and *Ford* elements are no more adjectives than *Francis* and *Scott* are in *“Francis Scott Key”*.  In both cases, the entire multiword component is a proper noun.

Comment: The process by which an adjective is made from a noun with the same form is called conversion or null-derivation, and it is very common in English.

Comment: @tchrist absolutely not. The essential defining syntactic characteristic of a proper noun is that it doesn't take a determiner in forming a noun phrase. _2003 Ford F-150_ is __clearly__ a bare noun, the only question is about that noun's internal structure

Comment: The Netherlands, the United States, and the United Kingdom are all going to be delighted to hear that they have been demoted from being a proper noun due to their determiners, as no doubt shall the New York Yankees and *The Odyssey*.

Comment: @tchrist ...fair. Proper nouns never take "a" -- it doesn't even make sense to talk about an indefinite proper noun

Comment: Nouns are not “converted” into adjectives when used attributively. If you’ve lost your *pen cap* while you were climbing the *orange tree* to fetch your *fighter kite* that got stuck there, then *pen, orange,* and *fighter* do not “convert” to adjectives; they remain nouns. However, if you did so by the light an *orange sunset*, then that second instance of *orange* would indeed be an adjective. You can tell the difference because of the stress in *orange tree* being different from that in *orange sunset*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16179/discussion-between-colinro-and-tchrist).