# In the adjective+preposition collocation, can any other word occur in between them?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, collocation

> I am *hungry for* breakfast

is an example of such collocation while

> I have *lived by* the bay area

isn't because it has a slightly different grammatical pattern.

My question is whether there are sentences like

> I am *hungry* in XYZ *for* ABC.

in general and in particular as stated above?

Comment: 'I am hungry in the worst way for breakfast',

Comment: @Mitch. That's good: it works because (at least semantically) "hungry in the worst way" functions as a complex verb which still has _for breakfast_ as its complement.

Answer (score 2):

"I am hungry in the morning for breakfast" looks like it fits the bill.

Comment: I find it awkward, and just barely acceptable, though.

Comment: What @Colin said. I think [almost?] all native speakers would much prefer *I am hungry for breakfast in the morning*. Is there a recognized "Royal Order of Adverbial Clauses" as with [adjectives?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/)

Comment: This is not a case of two adverbial clauses. _For breakfast_ is a complement of _hungry_; _in the morning_ is an adjunct. The normal order is for arguments (eg complements) to be closer to the head than adjuncts. There are circumstances in which this is overridden, but this is the normal rule.