# "the best two" vs "the two best"

Tags: grammar, word-order

I can't seem to find which one of these two wordings is correct:

> In 2014, the **best two** submitted runs were from unsupervised systems.
>
> In 2014, the **two best** submitted runs were from unsupervised systems.

Context: In 2014, multiple runs have been submitted. The first and second rank were unsupervised systems. Is there any difference in both variants? I'm currently using the first one but I'm struggling ;)

Comment: Both are correct. You can learn more about adjective order here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order

Comment: What @Qaz said. From [the runaway top answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/1159/2637) on the original: ***Numbers usually go before adjectives.***