# What is the reason behind the royal order of adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Can anyone explain the reason behind the order of adjectives? Why do we say

> the small brown antique house

Rather than

> the brown small antique house

or

> the antique brown small house

I'm familiar with [the Royal Order](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order), but I'm looking for some type of reasoning behind this consistency.   **Why are adjectives ordered in a certain way? What is the history behind the order?**

Comment: The purported duplicate does not address the _reason/s_ behind the 'royal order', though answers there address the plethora of guidelines and exceptions in the ordering of sequential adjectives in great detail.

Comment: Looking for _reasons_ why language is the way it is, is mostly a waste of time. Language **is**. In most cases nobody designed it, or decided that it should be that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we order our adjectives in certain ways: "big, blue house" rather than "blue, big house"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/599423/why-do-we-order-our-adjectives-in-certain-ways-big-blue-house-rather-than-b) (Refer to [this meta-post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15644/what-should-be-done-with-the-questions-that-ask-about-the-reason-behind-adjectiv?cb=1) to clarify/discuss)