# What is the reason for the 'royal' order of adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis

Why do we say "a big ugly cat" and not "an ugly big cat" according to the order of adjectives (opinion first then size)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

Comment: [This has actually been asked here before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333362/the-order-of-adjectives), but wrongly closed as a duplicate. The 'duplicate' did not ask for the reason the 'order' is such as it is.

Comment: What about *The **Big Bad Wolf***? or ablaut reduplication: chit-chat, flip-flop? Do they follow this rule?

Comment: ... But the 'Ugly Great Giant' and an 'ugly great ditch'? Often, 'how it sounds' is a significant factor.

Comment: Context can make all the difference. Absent context, we'd probably say ***the big bad thumb*** sounds more "natural", but not in something like *He's got a badly infected swollen thumb. Luckily, he's left-handed, and the **bad big thumb** is on his right hand, so he can still write properly*.

Comment: Because that is the way English works. No other reason.

Comment: *Why* is entirely opinion based.