# Two adjectives in a row: word order

Tags: word-order

Which is correct:

She is married to a tall broad-shouldered man, or
She is married to a broad-shouldered tall man?

Thanks.

Comment: In the variant of the 'Royal Order of Adjectives' given [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order/49632#49632), size comes before shape. Of course, you then have to decide (1) whether to count 'broad-shouldered' as size [b] or shape, and (2) how much faith to put into the ROoAdjs. I've seen different lists (ie orders), and articles dealing with failures of the particular list suggested. //  I'd certainly choose your first order here; the other sounds unnatural.

Comment: ... However, '... broad-shouldered, tall and lean ...'  (shape - size - shape?) seems to trip off the tongue better than any of the other 5 permutations. I'd say cadence trumps semanto-syntactic prescriptivism here.

Comment: Generally speaking, "tall" would come before other adjectives.  It would, eg, be "tall red building", not "red tall building".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tall broad-shouldered man **sounds** correct compared to broad-shouldered tall man

There is also this list from:
http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/

Where I would like believe tall refers to size, and broad-shouldered refers to shape.

Comment: I answered in a 'comment' because (1) the bulk of this is duplicated material; (2) I can find no further support for what I judge to be best in this individual example. A Google search give both orderings (the tall,  b-s admittedly seems more common), but, especially with three adjectives, the reverse order seems fairly popular.