# Ordering of Similarly-Categorized Adjectives

Tags: adjectives, word-order

I realize that there is already [a very popular question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order) that discusses this question in depth, but I think this is a singular case.

How would the following adjectives be ordered?

> He is a brilliant, eccentric billionaire.
>
> He is an eccentric, brilliant billionaire.

On the linked question, it states the order as being:

> (5) Quality > Size > Shape > Color > Provenance [Sproat and Shih (1991)]
>
> (6) a. Possesive > Speaker-oriented > Subject-oriented >Manner/Thematic [Cinque (1994)]
>
> b. Value > Dimension > Physical property > Speed > Human Propensity > Age > Color [Dixon (1982)]

How would these two adjectives (brilliant and eccentric) fit into this? What would their order be?

Comment: _He is a brilliant but eccentric millionaire._ The contrast virtually demands more support than a comma. / Reversing the adjectives here is not unacceptable but shifts the focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the words 'brilliant' and 'billionaire' are so aurally similar, the sentence is more balanced when they are broken by your other adjective. Brilliant billionaire deposits all of the emphasis a the end of the sentence, weighing it down. "...brilliant, eccentric billionaire." definitely sounds more even and has better flow.