# How to use several adjectives afterwards

Tags: adjectives

While doing an English test I've found this question :

> A ___________ lives in that house.
>
> 1. fat, small man
> 2. small, man fat
> 3. man, fat small
> 4. small, fat man

---

Could someone give me an explanation of what's the right answer, and more importantly why?

Is there a difference between British and American English in this case?

Comment: Adjectives always before noun, order best answered here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order

Comment: @JonLarby ... not always, but usually.  And yes, in this case adjectives before noun.  So that says 2,3 are wrong.  But can we choose between 1,4?

Comment: @GEdgar According to the correction, the answer is 4. But I still don't know why.

Comment: @GEdgar According to [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fat+small+man%2Csmall+fat+man&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmall%20fat%20man%3B%2Cc0), most people make the same choice. The 'Royal order of adjectives' often works. But not always. English is English.