# Which order is right: "an ugly huge scar" or "a huge ugly scar"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Which of the following is right? Why?

1. He has an ugly huge scar on his face.
2. He has a huge ugly scar on his face.

I would choose the second one, but I don't know why.

Comment: There is an earlier question about the topic of adjective order in general: [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155)

Comment: In the article mentioned by @sumelic size comes first and then quality so it is considered (by the article) more 'natural' to say _huge ugly_. It is a conceptual matter of what impresses first in the mind's eye.

Comment: You chose the right one, go ahead. For the why of it, see previous posts. Good Luck.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that this is more opinion based than anything, but I think that it should be the second one because huge ugly means it is huge and ugly, but the first one means it is ugly and another thing is huge