# Which one is Correct? (Intuitive declarative syntax or declarative intuitive syntax)

Tags: grammar

Which one is Correct? and why?

**Intuitive declarative syntax**

or

**declarative intuitive syntax**

Is there a rule to make these expressions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really fall into the English adjective order nightmare, so by default I'd assume one of the adjectives is modifying the other. If you turned the outermost attributive into a predicate, which  one is what you were trying to say?

- (Intuitive declarative syntax) The declarative syntax is intuitive (for a novice programmer)!
- (Declarative intuitive syntax) The intuitive syntax is declarative.

Whichever of these two is what you were trying to say is the one that's correct.