# Using two adjectives in a sentence

Tags: grammar, british-english, speech, grammaticality

Is it correct to start a sentence with "Please find the attached revised invoice", with two adjectives (attached and revised) one after another?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

Comment: Adjective order doesn't appear to cover a situation where both adjectives are of the same "class".

Comment: @AndrewLeach Perhaps so, but it is clear enough that what has been attached is a revised invoice, and that it would be odd to say ‘the revised attached invoice’.

Comment: In simple terms, you are taking about an invoice. Which invoice? A **revised** invoice. The theme (the thing or matter the sentence/fragment addresses) is "revised invoice" which is now taken as a noun phrase. "Attached" therefore qualifies the whole noun phrase, and thus precedes it.

Answer (score 4):

There is certainly no problem in premodifying a noun with two or more adjectives. But you then need to decide:

- In which order should they be?
- Should they be separated by commas?

To answer these questions you need to understand the difference between   *coordinate* and *cumulative* adjectives:

> *Coordinate* adjectives are those that each separately modify the noun. For example, *an old, dilapidated house* or *a big, heavy box*.
>   The house is old and dilapidated, and the box is big and heavy. You need the comma and you
>   can remove either of the adjectives and still have a correct description:
>   *The old house*, *the heavy box*.
>
> *Cumulative* adjectives are those that modify the unit that follows
>   them. For example, *a bright red box*, which means that the box is red
>   and the red is bright. You cannot remove *bright* and have a fully
>   correct description: *a bright box*. Nor can you put *and* between the
>   adjectives: *the bright and red box* or switch them around: *a red
>   bright box* or put a comma between them: *a bright, red box*.

Whether adjectives are intended to be understood as *coordinate* or *cumulative* is not always clear-cut. In your case I regard them as *cumulative*.  It is the 'revised invoice' that is attached. *Please find the attached and revised invoice* does not sound right. This means that there should be no comma:

- ?*Please find the attached, revised invoice.*

and that the adjectives cannot be switched:

- ?*Please find the revised attached invoice.*

You could solve the problem by moving *attached* one word to the left:

- *Please find attached the revised invoice.*

Or if this is too formal, then simply:

- *The revised invoice is attached.*

Comment: Does 'You could solve the problem ...' mean that you also find 'Please find the attached revised invoice' problematic? It's the semanto-syntactico-punctuationally correct form, but ugly, if nowhere near as outlandish as that descriptor. I'd certainly prefer your workarounds.