# Why can’t I turn “fast-paced” into a quality noun by adding the “‑ness” sufﬁx?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word, descriptive-grammar, derivational-morphology

I needed to write a word that expressed the quality of being fast-paced.

"Fast-pacedness" sounded off and I looked the dictionaries up.

Collins is my favourite one. Webster I use when I need to give a word a casual glance. Oxford seems to have the most formal descriptions.

None of them contained the word.

Which leaves me thinking what's the criterion in the first place, for that not to be a possible word.

And of course, I rephrased my sentence and it looked much better then, but I remain with a question that's worth, I assume.

[EDIT]

The context was located inside a debate where it is assumed that the world changes very fast. There [supposedly] is a generalised fast-paced[ness] affecting and permeating basically everything, which was not there in the 18th century and before, and was [also supposedly] noted by writers beginning in the 19th and ahead.

Although there's no sources or quotes about these supposed writers, the book that started the discussion repeats this assertion often, and I wanted to capture this quality of being fast-paced in a single word. There are other aspects not related to velocity, but change, but I was not concerned about that for a choice of words.

Comment: Could you give the whole sentence. We normally require context for a phrase not just a few isolated words. Thanks.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica context provided. I hope it suffices.

Comment: This is a grey area. See my comment below for four overproductivenesses you would do well to avoid. By 'quality' I assume you mean 'seen by almost all to be totally acceptable'. Your reticence is a clue here, as is the dearth of listings in quality dictionaries. It's clear what the candidate means, and '-ness' _is_ a very (but I'd strongly argue not totally) productive suffix. I'd certainly use your candidate in informal prose, but would re'word' in a formal ... article, say.

Comment: Some "past participle adjectives" can be idiomatically nounified with the ***-ness*** suffix *(**farsightedness, indebtedness,...**).* But many others (including OP's "coinage") look a bit peculiar. The noun for adjectival ***delighted*** isn't normally ***delightedness*** - it's just ***delight***. And for ***content*** it's usually ***contentment*** rather than ***contentedness***. But even if there *is* a "non-ness" version of the word available, that doesn't mean the "-ness" form isn't a "word". It's just much less likely to be used.

Comment: Have you considered "fast pace"? The noun form is already there.

Comment: i've seen "fast paced ness" (with/without various hyphens) any number of times in the startup scene, eg in job ads.  it's of no consequence

Comment: How would that be different from simple "pace"?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Why sure you can, and indeed you have just done so!

I really cannot imagine what it is that makes you think you cannot do what you have just yourself done. Do you mistrust your own eyes?  What’s the source of your afraidness here regarding *fast-pacedness*?

Perhaps it’s just its nonceness or ad-hoc-ness, its brand-newness or its yuckiness, or even its unapproachableness, but those are all their own concerns unrelated to what you have created.

Why? Because *-ness* is particularly superpowered among English derivational suffixes, that’s why. It does what it pleases, as too should you.  It is a suffix of neverending plentifulness, for its cornucopiousness knows no bottom!

I strongly recommend that you read Aranoff and Fuhrhop’s 2002 paper on [Restricting Suffix Combinations in German and English: Closing Suffixes and the Monosuffix Constraint](https://www.sunysb.edu/commcms/linguistics/faculty/mark.aronoff/files/Restricting%20suffix%20combinations%20in%20English%20and%20German.pdf), published in the journal *Natural Language & Linguistic Theory*.

There you will learn that *-ness* is the most liberal of all derivational suffixes, one that freely combines with nearly any base, even atop Latinate bases or piling atop not merely Germanic bases but even other Germanic suffixes, two things that just never happen with other Germanic derivational suffixes.

That’s why you can have *cluelessness* but not *cluenessless*. Heck, you can even have *admissibleness*! It doesn’t even have to be one word, which is where *anal retentiveness* comes into the picture.

So do as you will with your *fast-pacedness*. Just consider it your superpoweredness shining through. Eventually your friends may tire of your shock-and-awe-ness, but don’t let them hold you back! Be creative!

## The OED Speaks

The OED says that the twin etymons of *paced* the adjective are *pace* the verb combined with the *-ed* inflectional morpheme. The verb appeared in print a couple of centuries after the noun, which dates to 1300. The primary sense they give for the adjective is:

> 1. Having a particular pace, gait, or rate of walking or moving. Chiefly as the second element in compounds.
>    For more established compounds, see the first element; recorded earliest in **well-paced** *adj.* 1, with reference to a woman metaphorically likened to a horse.

(Sense 1 is the one that applies here; their senses 2 and 3 are for other sorts of uses.)

Here is that earliest citation just now mentioned:

- ?**1523** J. Fitzherbert *Bk. Husbandry* f. xxxiᵛ
     The first [property of a woman] is to be mery of chere, the seconde to be well pased.

As you see, spelling was not yet at all standardized during late Middle English. They then proceed to illustrate the historical progression of the dominant spellings used over many centuries, including in this order and beginning with the first just given: *well pased, slowe paste, high-pac’d, slowly pac’d, middle paced, slow-pac’d, stealthy-paced, **quick-paced***.

Elsewhere in the OED they separately document all of *broken-paced, easy-paced, fine-paced, firm-paced, giddy-paced, half-paced, heavy-paced, lazy-paced, lofty-paced, medium-paced, motor-paced, proud-paced, **quick-paced**, slow-paced, snail-paced, **swift-paced**, tandem-paced, thorough-paced, tortoise-paced, true-paced.*

As you see, it’s used in really all sorts of compounds, many of them rather more unusual that you own. Honestly, given *quick-paced* and *swift-paced*, not to mention *slow-paced* and *tortoise-paced*, what can possibly be “wrong” with your *fast-pacedness*? It lacks but a *-ness*, which is covered in the section previous to this one and in the section subsequent to this one alike.

Their most recent citation included under the *paced* headword is *ideally paced*, which is an open compound:

- **1990**   *Gramophone* May 1982/2
     A buoyant, ideally paced scherzo whose refulgent second subject Litton pointedly relishes even more on its second appearance.

My personal conclusion, based solely on OED inspection alone, is that your own version is unremarkable, no matter whether viewed diachronically or synchronically.

## Published Citations of *-pacedness*

Here for your delectation are a couple of centuries’ worth of references to published instances
of various sorts of *X-pacedness* terms. I see no difference whatsoever between *swift-pacedness* or *slow-pacedness* and the asker’s *fast-pacedness*.

- **1823** *European Magazine and London Review*, Volume 84, p 141.
  This **thorough-pacedness** has communicated itself to his pleasures as well as
  his labours; and he runs through the business of relaxation with
  earnestness, because he has deliberated and resolved upon it.
- **1836** Isaac Taylor *The Characters of Theophrastus*, p. 77
  In this movement there is that peculiar character of **even-pacedness** which
  belongs to all the undisturbed operations of nature.
- **1884** L.H. Grindon *Life: Its Nature, Varieties, and Phenomena*, p. 397
  Virtue, wisdom, poetry, the Bible, are matters which from intellectual
  **slow-pacedness**, or moral disrelish, excite only moieties of interest,
  but life is the central, universal, indomitable solicitude.
- **1892** *The American Magazine*, Volume 34, p. 349
  Scientific development has invested most things with a modern air of
  improvement and utility that contrasts violently with the staidness and
  **slow-pacedness** so characteristic of the age of our grandfathers.
- **1903** E.V. Lucas *The Works of Charles and Mary Lamb: Letters, 1796-1834*, p. 14
  Your simile of the Laplander..will bear comparison with any in Milton for
  fullness of circumstance and **lofty-pacedness** of Versification.
- **1983** S.G. Abbas *The Immortal Poetry & Mir Anis*, p. 174
  Very like the presentation of the qualities of the sword, Anis made a
  description of the grace, faithfulness, agility, trot and **swift-pacedness**
  of the horse.
- **1985** J.M. Heath and M. Payne *Text, Interpretation, Theory*, p 170
  ..to Tennyson's use of “the most characteristic of the Keatsian
  metonymies, which is the substitution of a near-stasis or **slow-pacedness**
  for the language of the sense, for the sounds and sights of passing time.”
- **1985** Peter Clark *A Review of the Theories of Time and Structure for Organizational Sociology*, p. 31
  Probably the other most important dimensions requiring investigation are
  societal expectations about the **even pacedness** of working and excitement
  control (Elias, 1982).
- **1994** *Industrial & Labor Relations Review* Volume 48, p. 335
  We then ran preliminary regressions with salaried status as the dependent
  variable and a “**pacedness**” variable (combining the three measures of
  **pacedness** into one) as one of the independent variables..
- **1999** K. Jahandarie *Spoken and Written Discourse: A Multi-disciplinary Perspective*, p. 133
  In his *Dialogues on the Differences Between Speaking and Writing*, Pedro de
  Navarra, the 16th-century Spanish linguist, referred to several such
  differences, including the evanescence, contextuality, **other-pacedness**, and
  redundancy of speech vs. the permanents, autonomy, **self-pacedness**, and
  conciseness of writing
- **2012** M.S. Frings *Philosophy of Prediction and Capitalism*, p. 3
  This **slow-pacedness** of philosophical thinking does not, however, agree very
  well with the restless speed of our lives and present-day cravings for ever
  faster short-term solutions of all impending problems.

And although these terms may not be especially popular for any number of possible reasons, they are certainly morphologically grammatical
and can be found here and there in various published works from the past 200 years.

---

#### <sup>*Post script*</sup>

***No*** dictionary can ever tell you something is ***not*** a word!

Comment: I confess I laughed, because your answer was just so funny to read. Yet it delivered a compelling argument. I think I'll just leave it open for now so as to see what comes next. It is always good to see all the perspectives coming up.

Comment: But apart of that, I think my language insecurities are just a side-effect of being open-minded and always eager to learn more. I never consider what I know as definite, so indeed when I have the slightest doubt, I ask.

I was also concerned about the *academicness* of the term, maybe so more than anything else, haha.

Thanks for taking the time, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Can you envision _part-timeness_, _deep-waterness_, _six-pagedness_ being considered acceptable in any but the most jocund of submissions? There are some in grave need of an injection of Orwell-VIness.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A great deal more research and analysis underlies my answer’s ultimate ruling on the morphological grammaticality of *fast-pacedness* than you may appreciate, but once I had decided to provide an answer both brief and breezy, exposing any more of that iceberg than its tiniest tip risked putting both those goals at risk of failure. I can certainly provide those details if doing so might serve to reduce your displeasure, but as better men than I have lamented, I must needs regret said proof is too large to fit within the slim margin of the comment you've just finished reading.

Comment: [Here's a useful link to an OUP piece.](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/groupsioattachments/46209/60379004/2771/0?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJECNKOVMCCU3ATNQ&Expires=1611765385&Signature=ebdTUkNr2r5nQz4OVGAeSUAufUg%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22RP.pdf%22) They mostly treat ***-edness*** and ***-edly*** as a unit, but there are certainly some interesting examples (***estrangedness*** and  ***assuredness*** aren't quite on a par with ***ashamedness*** and ***pleasedness***, for example). Plus it does address the issue of ***change over time***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your link does not resolve.

Comment: How about [this link?](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/groupsioattachments/46209/60379004/2771/0?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJECNKOVMCCU3ATNQ&Expires=1611771604&Signature=lfK6c9vQb51x7p0UpFNNS883cjI%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22RP.pdf%22)

Comment: (Dunno what happened with the first one, but browser remembered the history so I could find it again. It's a pdf "download", but not too big.)

Comment: A note on pronunciation, called to mind by @FumbleFingers 's comment mentioning -edness: I think "fast-pacedness", along with "assuredness" and maybe some of the other examples, would most naturally be pronounced with the "ed" as a syllable by itself, "fast-pace-ed-ness". To a modern ear, that might sound a bit archaic, but to me the other way sounds worse. I wonder if that's contributing to your confoundedness.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nope, those never work; they have built-in TTLs that are quite brief. That returns `<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<Expires>2021-01-27T18:20:04Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2021-01-27T18:59:34Z</ServerTime>
<RequestId>B9B008F91354CE62</RequestId>
<HostId>VQ9QWsmRZfpjeAWns0k4wN1FsD8flX1FfElEjeswY1Fjh8Q0/U8+uA/WyLQUIoBe2YJc+lKJMZ8=</HostId>
</Error>`

Comment: The whole thing needs refermatting.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "refermatting" Is that like, [widening the margins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Beware, I've heard warnings about (and note the nessness) [refermatness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reefer_Madness).

Comment: A dictionary can't tell you something isn't a word, but just because your coinage isn't in the dictionary, that doesn't necessarily mean another word with the meaning you want isn't already widely recognized.

Comment: @philipxy Fermat should have submitted an _answer_ rather than complaining about the restrictions accompanying _comments_.

Comment: Oh, well thanks for that info about "ephemeral links". I'll try to avoid posting them in future. Looking into it more closely I suspect I wasn't *supposed* to be able to access the full text of the post [without paying for it]. Whatever - I just noticed there's a typesetting error in the introduction, so googling the exact text "This first part of Pronunciationis concerned with general variations" should easily find it. On my system, that gets just **3** hits - one dead link, one link to the relevant .pdf, and one to a page trying to sell me a copy of *The Oxford Guide to English Usage*.

Comment: I disagree that a normal English speaker would opt for "admissibleness" over "admissibility." The "-ity" suffix is ubiquitous following "-able" or "-ible" because of derivation from "able" and "ability." I would certainly object to the use of "admissibleness" in formal writing. (The lesson here should be "follow the rules in formal writing unless you're being clever, but don't let anyone tell you how to speak in informal situations.")

Comment: @AndrewRay I never said that you “should”: you are no longer discussing actual grammar but mere preferences of style. The *‑ible/‑able* suffix does not block *‑ness*; it is not ungrammatical. **Please read the referenced paper in full.** The OED cites "1964 Jrnl. Biblical Lit. 83 377   The admissibleness of this hypothesis will have to depend solely on how well the other scraps of evidence will fit into this quite arbitrary framework." and gives its sense as equivalent to *admissibility*. It also states that as of 2012 it is “now *rare*”. But it is not ungrammatical, a fundamental distinction.

Comment: @tchrist Nor did I claim it was ungrammatical, merely that there is a more widely accepted alternative and that its use would be ill-advised in certain limited circumstances.

Comment: You can do amazing things with suffixes in English, but sometimes the results are awkwardnessful.

Comment: @PM2Ring No, that is not true. Sometimes the result are ***ungrammatical*** because they violate particular constraints. [Please read this paper](https://www.sunysb.edu/commcms/linguistics/faculty/mark.aronoff/files/Restricting%20suffix%20combinations%20in%20English%20and%20German.pdf). The monosuffix suffix forbids the form you suggested; it is not merely awkward: it is just as ungrammatical as [a green great dragon](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56874/2085) is. Complex underlying grammatical rules govern suffixation restrictions just as much as they do adjective ordering restrictions.

Comment: I tend to agree. FWIW, I didn't coin "awkwardnessful". Douglas R. Hofstadter used it in the introduction of *Gödel, Escher, Bach*.

Comment: Aside from replacing it with 'rapidity'  we have a family joke that any term can take any suffix, whether or not torturous or acceptable to the general populace. Hence you can always perform with fast-pacedness, fast-pacity or even fast-paceliness. So there! (Though sometimes we do it in public, which can attract … ermm… interest.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It turns out that *-paced* is fairly productive. See the added section with OED data.

Answer (score 14):

I can think of lots of possible alternatives, e.g.

alacrity,
briskness,
dispatch,
haste,
hurry,
hustle, etc.

However I don't think that is what you are asking. fast-pacedness sounds okay to me. I wouldn't want to overuse it though.

Notice that conventionally the pronunciation would change so as to clearly pronounce the "ed" syllable.

The original phrase "fast paced" is sounded as "fast paste". With the addition of "-ness" you would hear:

*fast pace-ed-ness*

Comment: The point about pronunciation is one of the most important things to be aware of. It applies to other words too, such as *fixedly*: *fik-sid-ly*, not **fixt-ly*.

Comment: I'm not that keen on ***diseasedness, detachedness,*** for example, but even if I *did* use them, I'd never actually enunciate the Past Partciple ***-ed*** element. I don't suppose any dictionaries would include ***fast-pacedness*** anyway - but if they *did*, I wouldn't expect to see it listed as ***four*** syllables. And [TheFreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/detachedness#:~:text=Standing%20apart%20from%20others%3B%20separate,personal%20interest%3B%20aloof%20or%20unbiased.) has ***detachedness*** (**dɪˈtætʃtnəs**) - *the quality of being detached or separated* (3 syllables).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The problem with "Pasteness" as it would sound under your scheme, is that it resembles the name of a heroine in a movie for young adults rather than a proper word.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: I don't know anything about that. But I do know that [*Upstart Crow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart_Crow) made great play of Robert Greene (mis)pronouncing ***-ed*** (in words like ***contained***, where it just sounds ***silly / humorous*** rather than ***learned***). And I personally probably wouldn't enunciate that ***-ed*** in ***fast-pacedness***, regardless of context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Upstart Crow is full of anachronisms and nonsensical humour. Pronunciation in Shakespeare's day was in flux and people were beginning to drop the clear "ed" in favour of the vowel-less version. Both could be heard in common use.  There are plenty of current English words that retain the full sound of "ed". I suggest that "fast-pacedness" is a suitable candidate because as a nonce word, it needs to be said distinctly or no-one will recognise it.  If it is pronounced "fastpasteness" it will be unintelligible to people who haven't heard it before.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: I know all that (did you miss my *"**learned**"* pun?). If you want to include the explicitly-enunciated ***-ed*** in ***fast-pacedness*** I can hardly stop you, but so far as I'm concerned it just sounds like something that should have been in *Upstart Crow* anyway! Would you still want to go down that route with, for example, [***unwashedness***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unwashedness%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01O9EnLUHdp40Xq7n8MlL6WEMK_vw:1611845069127&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_uZzm7r7uAhV8QxUIHbOGALkQpwUIJg&biw=1536&bih=732&dpr=1.25)? Yuck! :)

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: ***We*** may be as clean and pure as driven snow, but apparently Anglophones in general have needed to talk about their state of "unwashedness" far more often than I would have expected! I put in that link to Google Books because I knew there would have to be at least *some* instances of the term, but I never expected more than a handful of results. It turns out you can even [chart the word in NGrams.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unwashedness&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunwashedness%3B%2Cc0) Who'da thunk it?

Answer (score 4):

"pace" is already a noun. "pacedness" is a noun turned into an adjective turned into a noun. While it's not completely prohibited, it's a bit awkward. If you want to talk about the property of being fast paced, you should just say "fast pace": "There [supposedly] is a generalised fast pace affecting and permeating basically everything."

Comment: You may have missed a step there. The OED says *paced* came from the verb that was zero-converted from the noun, so it's the normal part-participle version of *-ed* that provided the adjective, **not** the other version of *-ed* used on nouns to derive adjectives like *snaggletoothed*.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the spirit of the question - specific answers about "fast-pacedness" have already been given.

In English (as with plenty of other languages) you can create words by composition- combining morphemes in different ways. Attaching prefixes or suffixes to a base word is an extremely common way to do that. Anything you can fabricate from morphemes is <s>technically a grammatically correct</s> an acceptable word to all but the strictest proponents of prescriptive grammar. (See comments.)

That said, just because something is *technically* not incorrect doesn't mean it should be used indiscriminately. At least, you should be aware of the way uncommon composite words sound to native speakers. The excellent answer from tchrist contains plenty of such words, and while they make the answer fun to read, even one of them makes it appear that [Doctor Seuss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh,_the_Thinks_You_Can_Think!) is writing.

"Cornucopious" is a rather advanced adjective. "Cornucopiousness" sounds exceedingly silly, which you might like in creative writing, but not a debate. "Afraidness" might be written to convey a very child-like or whimsical tone, but in everyday speech you will *always* hear "fear."

Comment: Your assertion that “anything you can fabricate with morphemes is technically a grammatical correct word” is **completely wrong**. That’s the key point of [the referenced paper](https://www.sunysb.edu/commcms/linguistics/faculty/mark.aronoff/files/Restricting%20suffix%20combinations%20in%20English%20and%20German.pdf). We have two disjoint sets of grammars, one governing Germanic suffixation and another Latinate suffixation. For example, adding Latinate *‑ation* to Latinate verb *accuse* makes *accusation*, but added to Germanic verb *clobber* results in ❌ *clobberation*, an ᴜɴɢʀᴀᴍᴍᴀᴛɪᴄᴀʟ form.

Comment: Sure, I concede that at the most technical level they are not grammatically correct. They will still be accepted as an English word by 99% of speakers (i.e. anyone without a language arts degree, and any descriptivists with one) to the same degree as the funny-sounding "cornucopiousness" would. Words like polyamorous, composed of a Greek prefix and a Latin base and suffix, indeed appear in Collins dictionary. That's the point I really want to make, and I'm happy to make a quick edit to avoid the impending prescriptive vs. descriptive debate

Comment: Darn, I guess you haven't read the paper after all, have you? There are firm suffixation restrictions that nobody will accept. It isn't a matter of language purism. These are the underlying real rules of English grammar which linguists have discovered, not made-up "rules" from school teachers who think they get to tell you how to talk.  Adding suffixes after *-ness* forms ungrammatical compounds forbidden by these restrictions. Attempts like *righteousnessdomshipicitarial*  simply cannot happen, and no native speaker will ever accept them.