# Are there any differences between ‘evolutionary’ and ‘evolutional’?

Tags: meaning, derivational-morphology

I heard the word *evolutional* quite recently and I’d
like to know whether this word has the same meaning as
*evolutionary* has. Do they have different
connotations?

My gut says that *evolutionary* is like praise while
*evolutional* is more logical. For example:

1. This artwork is **evolutionary**!
2. The **evolutional** fact is that predecessors either evolve to become successors or else go extinct.

Furthermore, do we have other examples similar to this
one where both words share the same part of speech
(both adjectives) yet have different suffixes, such as
here *‑ary* vs. *‑al*?

**Edit**: I found my answer from @Barmar's comment in the answer below. I misunderstood that evolutionary and revolutionary mean the same thing. This renders my gut feeling useless. But still, do they have any difference at all?

Comment: What does a dictionary comparison tell you?

Comment: _Evolutional_ is rare. The iWeb corpus has just 194 instances, against 87 thousand of _evolutionary_. It is so rare that most people won't have come across it, and will not have developed any semantic connotation for it. My advice it to pretend that it does not exist.

Comment: I don't know if this website is trustworthy, but Wikidiff says evolutional means 'of or pertaining to evolution' and evolutionary means 'of or relating to evolution'. I don't understand the difference between them. @KillingTime

Comment: @ColinFine Oh. That explains why I couldn't find anything about it except for the one Wikidiff link.

Comment: Is that really supposed to be a single text that uses both words? Or are they two unrelated quotes?

Comment: @Barmar : They're not "quotes" - they're just two examples (one an exclamation, the other a malformed noun phrase) illustrating what the OP thinks might be two different meanings associated with the two morphological derivations.

Comment: Perhaps "evolutional" is specialized jargon for some field.  But (unless you are writing for such a field) do not use it yourself.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/558699/2085).

Comment: There is a reasonable question in here, but both example show a total misunderstanding of proper usage. In 2. The statement is utterly backwards, as evolutionary processes are nearly always working against adaptive ones - returning a population to it's "normal" makeup after some adaptive pressures have been withstood which perturbed the population's diversity. Mutation almost never produces or contributes to speciation. Most mutations that survive in a population enable retention of traditional roles and niches and improve population cohesion.

Comment: Compare the above with _literary_ and _literal_. The first expresses the thing itself being a manner. The second expresses the thing itself as a state.

Comment: "Are there any differences between ‘evolutionary’ and ‘evolutional’?" - Yes, *evolutionary* has survived. *Evolutional* was used when Henry Spencer was trying to assemble the Victorian Era's version of a unified field theory. *Evolution* was the term for the one universal law from which all reality ensues. *Evolutional* was the normal adjective for this concept. The word barely survives because it's host died. I suspect *evolutionary* became attached to Darwinian evolution when Spencer's evolutional theory became lame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think that when we use evolutionary, we're talking about progress, for example *The changes were evolutionary.*
But when we say evolutional, it has the nuance of related to the process of evolution, for example *Evolutional successor*. Notice how if we say evolutionary, the nuance of the sentence immediately changes to, as someone said, something like praise. The difference is subtle, and I know it intuitively, so apologies if the answer wasn't articulate enough haha
Also, take this with a grain of salt because I haven't really seen the word evolutional much, so I'm just going with my gut feeling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The only dictionary definitions of _evolutionary_ I've come across either relate to the theories (general; special) or to general change that is gradual rather than abrupt. No allusion to praiseworthiness.

Comment: Perhaps some people think *an **evolutionary** new product* is more "evolved" (read, "improved") than the somewhat cliched [***revolutionary** new product.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=revolutionary+new+product&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suspect the author of the first quote in the question was simply misuising "evolutionary" when they meant "revolutionary". It's not clear why the former would be an exclamation.

Comment: @Barmar Ah. I think I found the answer from you right here. The author in question for both quotes is me. I misunderstood that both 'evolutionary' and 'revolutionary' mean the same thing. Whoops.

Comment: NB: *evolutionary* occurs about 1,000× more often than *evolutional* does in modern written English. They likely have slightly different meanings as well. See also *evolutive, evolvent, evolutionistic* — amongst others.

Answer (score 1):

According to MWD:
When used to transform a noun into and adjective, the suffixes:

- [-al](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-al): of, relating to, or characterized by
  directional; fictional
- [-ary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ary): of, relating to, or connected with
  budgetary

The distinction is only relevant when there is a desire to emphasize that the adjective describes something that is characterized by and not connected with the noun it modifies.

For example:
***Evolutional** Biology is a subfield of biology that studies the ***evolutionary** processes* that produce the diversity of life on Earth.*

This seems to be an example where the distinction may properly be discerned. However, it is a restatement of the [Wiki description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_biology) which prefers the use of *evolutionary* in both places. Moreover, my browser does not recognize *evolutional* and redirects to search results for *evolutionary biology*.  There is, happily,  an entry for [evolutional](https://%20https://www.thefreedictionary.com/evolutional) in thefreedictionary which provides links for other mentions in the wild.

Consider also - revolutional/revolutionary:

- *The discovery of penicillin had a **revolutional** impact on our ability to treat bacterial infections.*
- *The American ***Revolutionary*** War was a military conflict that lasted from April 1775, to September 1783.*

As used above, *impact* is more precisely described as *characterized by revolution*, than *connected with revolution* which is better used to describe the *Revolutionary War* in the second sentence. Again thefreedictionary has an entry for [revolutional](https://%20https://www.thefreedictionary.com/revolutional), albeit sparse, likewise [MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolutional).

With their prominent placements in both definitions, *of* and *relating to* can serve to make the case that the two suffixes are synonymous and other factors better determine which form to use. Not even thefreedictionary has entries for *budgetal*, *directionary*, or *fictionary*. It’s probably something to do with their etymology, but that’s further beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I can see a need to differentiate "pertaining to a revolution" from "causing a revolution" - for instance "revolutionary literature" could be literature about the American Revolution, or literature that causes a revolution in artistic expression. But I'm not sure there is a true difference between revolutionary and revolutional based on meaning, or at least not one most people agree on.