# OSASCOMP soft warm or warm soft? Does NOSACSCOMP offer the needed guidance?

Tags: adjective-position

Winter continues to chill us in Colorado. I enjoy lounging in my warm, soft sleep pants. Or are they soft and warm? I couldn't figure out which OSASCOMP category warm belongs in. To me, soft seems like a material. I found [Adjectives  Word Order Woodward English](https://www.woodwardenglish.com/lesson/adjectives-word-order/), which adds number and condition to opinion, size, age, shape, color, origin, material, and purpose: NOSCASCOMP. Can I trust the NOSCASCOMP guidance? In that case, maybe it doesn't matter because warm and soft could both be considered the condition of the pants. Or was my first instinct correct, that soft belongs to the material category?

Comment: This probably will get better answers in ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, done https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/276423/10787 thank you

Comment: Don't worry too much about it, most native speakers had never heard of the order rule until recently, we do put adjectives in order but we do it instinctively. The order rule is real but is just a reflection of the normal practice. Personally I would regard both 'soft' and 'warm' as opinion adjectives since they are subjective qualities. I would probably say 'soft, warm' myself but don't ask me why. Having said that I would say 'soft, warm, blue, brushed cotton sleep pants so that reduces your options.

Comment: I've heard of "preferred order", but I don't recall ever seeing "OSASCOMP" before this.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order for one of the many duplicates of the “adjective order” question, this one with a highly rated answer.

Comment: This site adds physical quality to the list.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/adjectives-order   I also think soft and warm are Opinion adjectives.